# SQL: Having a table twice in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-error-1054

I am using MySQL. Here is my schema:

Suppliers(**sid: integer**, sname: string, address string)

Parts(**pid: integer**, pname: string, color: string)

Catalog(**sid: integer, pid: integer**, cost: real)

(primary keys are bolded)

I am trying to write a query that selects pairs of `sid`s that supply the same part:

```
-- Find pairs of SIDs that both supply the same part
SELECT s1.sid, s2.sid
FROM Suppliers AS s1, Suppliers AS s2
JOIN Catalog ON s1.sid = Catalog.sid OR s2.sid = Catalog.sid;
```

MySQL gives me this error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column
>   's1.sid' in 'on clause'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find parts with two or more suppliers:

```
select part_id
from catalog 
group by part_id
having count(part_id) >= 2
```

find the supplier(s) of those parts, more future-proof, can show two or more suppliers:

```
select c.part_id, s.supplier_name 
from catalog c
join supplier s
where c.part_id in (
    select part_id
    from catalog 
    group by part_id
    having count(part_id) >= 2)
order by c.part_id, s.supplier_name
```

but if you want parts which exactly has two suppliers only:

```
select c.part_id, group_concat(s.supplier_name) as suppliers 
from catalog c
join supplier s using(supplier_id)
where part_id in (
    select part_id
    from catalog 
    group by part_id
    having count(part_id) = 2)
group by c.part_id
```

if you want only those two suppliers to display in two columns..  me thinking too... :-)

[UPDATE]

what i thought up:

```
select c.part_id, c.min(c.supplier_id) as first, c.max(c.supplier_id) as second 
from catalog c
join supplier s
where c.part_id in (
    select part_id
    from catalog 
    group by part_id
    having count(part_id) = 2)
group by c.part_id
order by c.part_id
```

to get the supplier names:

```
select x.part_id, a.supplier_name, b.supplier_name from
(
    select c.part_id, c.min(c.supplier_id) as first, c.max(c.supplier_id) as second 
    from catalog c
    join supplier s
    where c.part_id in (
        select part_id
        from catalog 
        group by part_id
        having count(part_id) = 2)
    group by c.part_id
    order by c.part_id
 ) as x
 join supplier a on x.first = a.sid
 join supplier b on x.second = b.sid
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 JOIN syntax - you can only use one, or the other.  ANSI-92:

```
   SELECT s1.sid, s2.sid
     FROM CATALOG c
LEFT JOIN SUPPLIERS s1 ON s1.sid = c.sid
LEFT JOIN SUPPLIERS s2 ON s2.sid = c.sid
```

Omit the `LEFT` keyword if you want to see categories with two suppliers associated.

ANSI-89 syntax has all the tables involved declared in the FROM clause, joins are in the WHERE clause.

Use ANSI-92 - [see this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/in-mysql-queries-why-use-join-instead-of-where).

Comment: @wwosik: Me too, but with the `OR` it's more likely they could be optional.

Comment: If I understand it well, OP wants pairs of suppliers that both supply a thingie X. He doesn't want products which are supplied only by one or none suppliers. That's why I deleted my comment...

Comment: @wwosik: I added more info, but the orig. query is joining to the same column - the values will be duplicates.

Comment: At the moment I think you got it sort of wrong. It will match every product from Catalog twice with the same supplier who delivers it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are joining s2 and Catalog.  s1 doesn't exist in that clause.

Comment: If that were the case, you wouldn't be able to join to the `s2` alias either.

Comment: Both are declared on the same line, within the same clause.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: different definitions of clauses, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the error message, but:

I would avoid using join in this case.  Try this

```
SELECT s1.sid, s2.sid
FROM suppliers s1,
     suppliers s2,
     catalog   c1,
     catalog   c2
WHERE c1.pid = c2.pid
AND   s1.sid = c1.sid
AND   s2.sid = c2.sid
AND   s1.sid < s2.sid
```

Although since all you're asking for is the sids, it can be simpler:

```
SELECT c1.sid, c2.sid
FROM catalog   c1,
     catalog   c2
WHERE c1.pid = c2.pid
AND   c1.sid < c2.sid
```

Comment: Your first example is actually an inner join, just a hidden one (or rather tree).

Comment: But then the only rows returned have `s1.sid = s2.sid = c1.sid = c2.sid` ... I suspect the "pairs" of `suppliers` he wants have different `sid` keys.

Comment: @Joe, you have a good point, although you're not correct.  The join between the catalog tables is not on `sid`; it's on `pid`.  The good point is that we should exclude pairs of identical catalogs; I'll fix that.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and I'd just replace != with a < so we don't get symetric duplicates (Supplier1, Supplier2) and (Supplier2, Supplier1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explicity join all the tables if you will be using explicit joins.

e.g.

```
-- Find pairs of SIDs that both supply the same part
SELECT 
  s1.sid, 
  s2.sid
FROM 
  Catalog 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  Suppliers AS s1,
    ON Catalog.sid = s1.sid

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
  Suppliers AS s2
    ON Catalog.sid = s2.sid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join catalog with itself

```
SELECT 
    pid, 
    c1.sid, 
    c2.sid
FROM Catalog c1
JOIN Catalog c2 ON c1.pid = c2.pid AND c1.sid < c2.sid
```

< condition is to avoid pairs (A supplies same X as B so B supplies same X as A)