# Nested joins hide table names

Tags: sql, join, sqlite

I have three tables: Suppliers, Parts and Types. I need to join all of them while discriminating columns with the same name (say, "id") in the three tables. I would like to successfully run this query:

```
CREATE VIEW Everything AS
SELECT Suppliers.name as supplier, 
       Parts.id, 
       Parts.description, 
       Types.typedesc as type
FROM Suppliers JOIN (Parts JOIN Types ON Parts.type_id = Types.id)
ON Suppliers.id = Parts.supplier_id;
```

My DBMS (sqlite) complains that "there is not such a column (Parts.id)". I guess it forgets table names once the JOIN is done but then how can I refer to the column `id` that belongs to the table `Parts`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ANSI-92 JOIN syntax is incorrect - use:

```
CREATE VIEW Everything AS
  SELECT Suppliers.name as supplier, 
         Parts.id, 
         Parts.description, 
         Types.typedesc as type
    FROM Suppliers 
    JOIN Parts ON Suppliers.id = Parts.supplier_id
    JOIN Types ON Parts.type_id = Types.id
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are qualifying the join based on the table Alias.Field name, you should have no problem... such as

```
CREATE VIEW Everything AS 
      SELECT 
            Suppliers.name as supplier, 
            Parts.id, 
            Parts.description, 
            Types.typedesc as type 
         FROM 
            Suppliers,
            Parts,
            Types
         WHERE
                Supplier.ID = Parts.Supplier_ID
            AND Parts.Type_ID = Types.ID
         ORDER BY
            (whatever columns)
```

Comment: Ick, implied joins, please don't encourage people to use this poor programming technique.

Comment: +1: ANSI-89 join syntax is valid, it's just not preferred (mostly because of no standard OUTER JOIN syntax).  For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/in-mysql-queries-why-use-join-instead-of-where