# MySQL Search Query - Searching from tags, too :(

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

So, I've got a webapp that lets users submit code. The submissions are stored in the `code` table, and a couple of columns of that are Fulltext-Indexed. This is how I have been performing searches up until now.

But, users can submit their submissions with as many tags as they like - and I'd like these to be included in the search too (but, all in one query...). The tags are stored in the table `tags`, and there's an intersection table called `code_tags` that stores the `code_id` and the `tag_id`. Standard stuff.

My 'old' search query was this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM code
 WHERE MATCH (title, summary, code) AGAINST ('$searchterm')
```

`$searchterm` was fetched via PHP $_POST.

So I tried to write a bit more of an 'advanced' query:

```
SELECT code.*, 
       code_tags.*, 
       tags.*, 
       tags.tag
  FROM code, code_tags, tags
 WHERE code_tags.code_id = code.id
   AND tags.id = code_tags.tag_id
   AND MATCH (title, summary, code) AGAINST ('$searchterm')
```

But all this did was return... *nothing*. Even when a perfectly valid search term was entered.

So I commented out the last line:

```
SELECT code.*, code_tags.*, tags.*, tags.tag
  FROM code, code_tags, tags
 WHERE code_tags.code_id = code.id
   AND tags.id = code_tags.tag_id
-- AND MATCH (title, summary, code) AGAINST ('php')
```

This returns every submission in the database. But, the same row is repeated as many times as there are tags for it (the only difference being, the tag in each returned row).

E.G:

[image: Query Fail]

So, **finally**, I thought I'd be clever and GROUP_CONCAT the tags:

```
SELECT code.*, code_tags.*, tags.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag SEPARATOR ' ') AS taggroup
  FROM code, code_tags, tags
 WHERE code_tags.code_id = code.id
   AND tags.id = code_tags.tag_id
-- AND MATCH (title, summary, code, taggroup) AGAINST ('php')`
```

There are two pretty big problems with this.

1. With the last `AND MATCH` line commented out, only one row is returned (with all the details of the first entry in the `code` table - and taggroup lists every tag, for every submission!
2. With the last `AND MATCH` line included, I get the following error: `Unknown column 'taggroup' in 'where clause'` - damn!

So, what am I meant to do? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the following:

```
SELECT code.*, code_tags.*, tags.*, tags.tag
  FROM code, code_tags, tags
 WHERE code_tags.code_id = code.id
   AND tags.id = code_tags.tag_id
   AND MATCH (title, summary, code) AGAINST ('php')
```

...doesn't return any results is that you don't have any `code` table records whose title/summary/code match "php" AND have relations to either the `CODE_TAGS` or `TAGS` tables.  Switching to ANSI-92 JOIN syntax, try:

```
SELECT c.*, ct.*
  FROM CODE c
  JOIN CODE_TAGS ct ON ct.code_id = c.id
 WHERE MATCH (title, summary, code) AGAINST ('php')
```

If nothing is returned, then you're problem is that none of the records that satisfy the Full Text Search are related to anything in the `CODE_TAGS` table -- you'll need to add associations before it will work.  That should shine some light on if adding the JOIN to the TAGS table will affect anything:

```
SELECT c.*, ct.*
  FROM CODE c
  JOIN CODE_TAGS ct ON ct.code_id = c.id
  JOIN TAGS t ON t.id = ct.tag_id
 WHERE MATCH (title, summary, code) AGAINST ('php')
```

Comment: Hey OMG Ponies (best username ever)! OK, so I really appreciate the help. But, why do we need to switch to this ANSI-92 JOIN syntax? I'm afraid I'm not quite as experienced as you, and my Table's Encoding offers nothing about ANSI-92 or whatever. Running the queries you provided, just returns blanks again. I'll make sure one more time my FULLTEXT indexes are set correctly, then report back...

Comment: @Jack Webb-Heller: For more info about using ANSI-89 vs ANSI-92 JOIN syntax, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/in-mysql-queries-why-use-join-instead-of-where.  I demonstrated in my answer about what do to in order to ferret out why rows aren't being returned - if the join to only CODE_TAGS isn't returning records, you need to add records in the CODE_TAGS table that do...

Comment: OK. So I had a read through that, and then I got the message about "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list" - TADA! i thought. But no, I was wrong. I correctly added fulltext indexing to all the relevant columns, but still that message persists. What's going on?! :'(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you can select `tags.*` and `GROUP_CONCAT` at the same time but been a while since I was working with MySQL now, anyway join your data in and group by the columns you want should work. Example below.

```
SELECT code.id, code.title, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag SEPARATOR ' ')
  FROM code
 INNER JOIN code_tags ON code.id = code_tags.code_id
 INNER JOIN tags ON code_tags.tag_id = tags.id
 WHERE MATCH (code.title, code.summary, code.code) AGAINST ('php')
 GROUP BY code.id, code.title
```

Comment: Hmmm... sort of! I can definitely see where you're coming from, but, I just tried this in my MySQL App and it won't return any data when we're matching AGAINST ('php') - or anything else totally, completely valid. Even when php appears in the Title (and not just in the tags)...

Comment: Even if you only do `MATCH(code.title) AGAINST ('php')`?? I didn't know how your tables looked so the example didn't include any other columns in the `SELECT`/`GROUP BY`

Comment: Nope. Your suggestion of `MATCH(code.title)` is perfectly valid for my database, but, still nothing! :S