# what is difference between 'where' and different 'joins' in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In MySQL queries, why use join instead of where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/in-mysql-queries-why-use-join-instead-of-where)

Joins are always confusing for me..can anyone tell me what is difference between different joins and which one is quickest and when to use which join and what is difference between join and where clause ?? Plz give ur answer in detail as i already read about joins on some websites but didn't get the concept properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than quote an entire Wikipedia article, I'm going to suggest your their article on [SQL Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

> An SQL JOIN  clause combines records
>   from two or more tables in a
>   database.  It creates a set that
>   can be saved as a table or used as is.
>   A JOIN  is a means for combining
>   fields from two tables by using values
>   common to each. ANSI standard SQL
>   specifies four types of JOINs: INNER,
>   OUTER, LEFT, and RIGHT. In special
>   cases, a table (base table, view, or
>   joined table) can JOIN  to itself in a
>   self-join.
>
> A programmer writes a JOIN predicate
>   to identify the records for joining.
>   If the evaluated predicate is true,
>   the combined record is then produced
>   in the expected format, a record set
>   or a temporary table, for example.

There is an older syntax that uses WHERE clauses to imply INNER JOINs.  While it works, and will produce queries that run exactly like queries specified with the INNER JOIN syntax, it is deprecated because most people find it more confusing.

Here's the documentation for the [MySQL JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html).

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, o.order_id, o.total
FROM customers c, orders o
WHERE c.id = o.customer_id
```

and this

```
SELECT c.customer_name, o.order_id, o.total
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer_id
```

make no difference on what is executed on the mysql server but the join is (imho) way more readable. Expecially for more complex joins:

Here is an article about the topic: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/04/14/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-join-and-where/