# 1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: sql, mysql, join, mysql-error-1052

I have 2 tables. `tbl_names` and `tbl_section` which has both the `id` field in them. How do I go about selecting the `id` field, because I always get this error:

```
1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT id, name, section
  FROM tbl_names, tbl_section 
 WHERE tbl_names.id = tbl_section.id
```

I could just select all the fields and avoid the error. But that would be a waste in performance. What should I do?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

SQL supports qualifying a column by prefixing the reference with either the full table name:

```
SELECT tbl_names.id, tbl_section.id, name, section
  FROM tbl_names
  JOIN tbl_section ON tbl_section.id = tbl_names.id
```

...or a table alias:

```
SELECT n.id, s.id, n.name, s.section
  FROM tbl_names n
  JOIN tbl_section s ON s.id = n.id
```

The table alias is the recommended approach -- why type more than you have to?

#### Why Do These Queries Look Different?

Secondly, my answers use ANSI-92 JOIN syntax (yours is ANSI-89).  While they perform the same, ANSI-89 syntax does not support OUTER joins (RIGHT, LEFT, FULL).  ANSI-89 syntax should be considered deprecated, there are many on SO who will not vote for ANSI-89 syntax to reinforce that.  For [more information, see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/in-mysql-queries-why-use-join-instead-of-where).

Comment: Confusing! Because nothing is actually removed from the SQL language, SQL-89 is a proper subset of SQL-92. The OP's syntax is valid SQL-92 syntax (and. unless I'm missing something, yours is valid SQL-89 syntax). I consider `INNER JOIN` to be 'depreciated' since SQL-92 introduced `NATURAL JOIN`.

Answer (score 23):

In your `SELECT` statement you need to preface your id with the table you want to choose it from.

```
SELECT tbl_names.id, name, section 
FROM tbl_names
INNER JOIN tbl_section 
   ON tbl_names.id = tbl_section.id
```

OR

```
SELECT tbl_section.id, name, section 
FROM tbl_names
INNER JOIN tbl_section 
   ON tbl_names.id = tbl_section.id
```

Comment: This only returns one of the `id` fields; the OP states "just select all the fields and avoid the error."  And, I don't vote for ANSI-89 syntax.

Comment: Agreed but the question was how to select the id field.

Answer (score 8):

You would do that by providing a fully qualified name, e.g.:

```
SELECT tbl_names.id as id, name, section FROM tbl_names, tbl_section WHERE tbl_names.id = tbl_section.id
```

Which would give you the id of tbl_names

Comment: See my comment to bluefeet's answer

Comment: It's not a 'fully qualified name', it is a range variable. When you omit an explicit range variable, SQL generates one that is the same as the table name. To better see what I mean, change your `FROM` clause `...FROM tbl_names tbl_names, tbl_section tbl_section WHERE...` - that is what the parser is doing to generate a range variable.

Answer (score 8):

Already there are lots of answers to your question, You can do it like this also. You can give your table an alias name and use that in the select query like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, name, section
FROM tbl_names as a 
LEFT JOIN tbl_section as b ON a.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution is a join with `USING` instead of `ON`. That way, the database "knows" that both `id` columns are actually the same, and won't nitpick on that:

```
SELECT id, name, section
  FROM tbl_names
  JOIN tbl_section USING (id)
```

If `id` is the only common column name in `tbl_names` and `tbl_section`, you can even use a `NATURAL JOIN`:

```
SELECT id, name, section
  FROM tbl_names
  NATURAL JOIN tbl_section
```

See also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 5):

What you are probably really wanting to do here is use the union operator like this:

```
(select ID from Logo where AccountID = 1 and Rendered = 'True')
  union
  (select ID from Design where AccountID = 1 and Rendered = 'True')
  order by ID limit 0, 51
```

Here's the docs for it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the id's in the two table varies then you want to join them, as such you can select to use an id from one-main table, say if you have `table_customes` and `table_orders`, and tha id for orders is like "**101**","**102**"..."**110**", just use one for customers

```
select customers.id, name, amount, date from customers.orders;
```