# How can I resolve an ambiguous column name error in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1052

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638520/1052-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous)

I have two tables, and I want to connect the tables by `sb_id` (`sb_id` is same for two tables).  So, I used my query like this:

```
SELECT Name, 
       class 
  FROM student_info,
       student_class 
 WHERE id = 1 
   AND student_info.sb_id = student_class.sb_id;
```

And it's showed error:

> 1052: 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Another thing,I want to show just a single result,by using "JOIN".

Answer (score 9):

That means that both tables have `id` and you need to prefix it with the table that it appears in (if it is the same in both, either will do).

```
SELECT
  name,
  class
FROM student_info, student_class
WHERE
  student_info.id=1
  AND student_info.sb_id=student_class.sb_id;
```

This will return a single result, as you desire, as long as there is exactly one record with `student_info.id=1` and a `student_class` record with a matching `sb_id`.  The result is the same as if you used `INNER JOIN` — in other words, both records must exist and are joined together.

The corresponding `INNER JOIN` syntax would look like this:

```
SELECT
  name,
  class,
FROM student_info
INNER JOIN student_class ON student_info.sb_id = student_class.sb_id
WHERE student_info.id = 1
```

Comment: Both are INNER JOINs - the first is ANSI-89 syntax, the later is ANSI-92.  Both queries should be using table aliases, unless you like re-typing full table names for every reference...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `WHERE` statment, you need to use:

```
where student_info.id=1
```

or:

```
where student_class.id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name,class 
FROM student_info,student_class 
WHERE student_info.sb_id=1 AND student_info.sb_id=student_class.sb_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.Name,a.class from student_info as a join student_class as b
on a.sb_id = b.sb_id
 where id=1;

Comment: no need to alias the tables, just specify the table in the where clause...

Answer (score 0):

Should your `where id=1` be `where student_info.sb_id = 1` ?

You could change it to a join like this:

`SELECT Name,class 
FROM student_info
INNER JOIN student_class ON student_info.sb_id = student_class.sb_id
WHERE student_info.sb_id=1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name,class from student_info join student_class on student_info.sb_id=student_class.sb_id where student_info.id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student_info.Name,student_info.class from student_info inner join student_class on student_info.sb_id=student_class.sb_id where student_info.id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

this means id column is present in both tables, just replace the id with student_info.id or student_class.id which ever is intended

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the ID column in the where clause with the table name. It is confused because ID is in both tables and it doesn't know which one you mean.

```
WHERE student_info.id=1
```

or

```
WHERE student_class.id=1
```

depending on which one you meant when you wrote the query.

Answer (score 0):

It's because both of your tables have `id` field, so you need to specify which `id` you want to use (you may or may not use table aliases, I prefer to use, but it's really up to you). Also, using `JOIN` for joining tables is much better practice than putting everything in `FROM`.  I'd rewrite your query to

```
SELECT Name,class 
from student_info si
INNER JOIN student_class sc ON (sc.sb_id = si.sb_id)
WHERE si.id = 1  // or sc.id =1, whatever makes sense
```