# Error Code: 1052 when INSERTing (ID in field list is ambiguous)

Tags: mysql, sql, ambiguous, mysql-error-1052, fieldlist

I am being thrown a really weird error code, judging that I have successfully INSERTed values using the same query in a similar schema.

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO part_approval (part_quote_key)
SELECT part_quote_key
FROM database.part_quote;
```

The part_approval table is empty and columns are either NULLable or have DEFAULT values.
The part_quote table looks like this:

```
part_quote_key  price      batch       part_key   quote_key
1               12.90      30          5          17        2014-06-03 15:53:18
2               22.87      15          8          17        2014-06-03 16:14:52
3               19.96      15          9          17        2014-06-03 15:53:18
4               24.52      15          10         17        2014-06-03 15:53:18
5               13.65      15          14         17        2014-06-03 16:14:52
```

The error details point to "Column part_key is ambiguous in field list". However, the part_key column is not even in my result list of the above SELECT statement.

In addition, I've used the following statement to populate a similar table and it worked:

```
INSERT INTO component_approval (component_quote_key)
SELECT component_quote_key
FROM database.component_quote;
```

Is there anything I am overlooking?

Thanks for all your help in advance,
Marius

Comment: Did you try running the 2 queries separately? Like just the select statement, and then insert with any random number.

Answer (score 0):

Please try running your query by qualifying the columns by prefixing the table name or alias.

Refer this simmilar question:
[1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638520/1052-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous)