# Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous when using IN clause

Tags: mysql

I have written a query on three tables that share the common key named **id**. When the values are returned from the inner select statements,the outer select is not able to resolve the **id**. I looked at the posts in stackoverflow like the one below:
[[1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638520/1052-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous])

It recommends that we use aliases to disambiguate the problem, however it does'nt seem to be working for me. Following is my query in mysql.

```
SELECT
  e2.`exchange_code` 
  e1.`id`,
  e1.`error_time`,
  e1.`last_update_time` 
FROM
  `exchange_error_details` e1,
  `exchange_products` e2
WHERE e1.`id` IN 
  (SELECT 
    id 
  FROM
    exchange_products) 
  AND e1.`id` NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    id 
  FROM
    mdd_suppressed_keys) 
  AND e1.`clear_time` IS NULL
```

Edit:

**exchange_error_details**

```
id                 error_time   clear_time  last_update_time    clear_ref_ticker
ADF.10052.1.Q.FEED  2014-11-25 10:36:25 \N  2014-11-25 02:36:25 THD
ADF.10052.1.Q.FEED  2014-11-28 13:50:06 2014-11-28 13:50:37 2014-11-28 13:49:51 AMLP
ADF.10052.1.Q.FEED  2014-11-28 13:53:08 2014-11-28 13:53:38 2014-11-28 13:52:44 ONVO
ADF.10052.1.Q.FEED  2014-11-28 13:55:09 2014-11-28 13:56:10 2014-11-28 13:54:54 ACAD
ADF.10052.1.Q.FEED  2014-11-28 13:58:10 2014-11-28 13:58:41 2014-11-28 13:57:56 HABT
```

**exchange_products:**

```
 id               exchange_code iso_code    issue_type  
ADF.10052.1.Q.FEED  10052        ADF           1    
ADF.10052.1.T.FEED  10052        ADF           1    
ADF.10074.1.T.FEED  10074        ADF           1    
ADF.11099.1.T.FEED  11099        ADF           1    
ADF.11099.14.T.FEED 11099        ADF          14
```

**mdd_suppressed_keys**

```
id                  user    date
ADF.10052.1.Q.FEED  droy    2015-03-09 03:16:22
HAM.17.41.Q.FEED    droy    2015-03-09 03:16:26
HAM.17.41.T.FEED    droy    2015-03-09 03:16:30
IND.114.1.T.FEED    droy    2015-03-09 03:16:22
SWX.4.41.Q.FEED     droy    2015-03-09 03:16:22
```

**Error Message**

```
1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: select e2.`exchange_code`, e1.`id`, e1.`error_time`, e1.`last_update_time` from `exchange_error_details` e1, `exchange_products`...

Error Code: 1052
Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.388 sec
```

**Why I wrote this query:**

I wish to return only those values from the *exchange_error_details* table whose **id** field matches the one in the *exchange_products table* and exclude out the ones present in the *mdd_suppressed_keys* table.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a cross join here. Did you intend for that? You should use the modern `JOIN` operators instead of the old comma syntax.

Comment: When you say "not working", what error are you getting and where in the query is it giving the error?

Comment: could you show up to 5 records for `exchange_error_details` and `exchange_products` tables please? we can't see what is relations between those 2 tables. which columns must be bind  to jojn tables?

Comment: What's in `exchange_control_info`?

Comment: Fixed the typo. it should be exchange_products.Sorry abt that.

Comment: @deb you are welcome! good luck with your project! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your structure correct, your query must be `LEFT JOIN`ed :)

Try:

```
SELECT
  e2.`exchange_code` 
  e1.`id`,
  e1.`error_time`,
  e1.`last_update_time` 
FROM
  `exchange_error_details` e1
LEFT JOIN
  `exchange_products` e2
ON
  e1.id = e2.id
WHERE e1.`id` IN 
  (SELECT 
    id 
  FROM
    exchange_control_info) 
  AND e1.`id` NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    id 
  FROM
    mdd_suppressed_keys) 
  AND e1.`clear_time` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
WHERE e1.`id` IN 
  (SELECT 
    exchange_control_info.id 
  FROM
    exchange_control_info) 
  AND e1.`id` NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    mdd_suppressed_keys.id 
  FROM
    mdd_suppressed_keys) 
  AND e1.`clear_time` IS NULL
```