# Error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two table :

news:

```
|id|title|image|timestamp|....
```

tags:

```
|id|books_id|...
```

for result:

```
("SELECT id,title,front_thumbs,short_desc,timestamp,counter,author,
  FROM " . NEWS . " LEFT JOIN " . TAGS . " ON " NEWS . ".id = " . TAGS . ".content_id WHERE 
" . TAGS . ".tags_id = ? AND approved = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10", $id)
```

but I see this error:

```
Error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
```

how do fix this error?

Comment: Which `id` do you want? `news.id` OR `tags.id`? You can have either OR both, you just need to add the table name - `SELECT news.id, ...` or `SELECT tags.id, ...` or `SELECT news.id, tags.id, ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638520/1052-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When both tables have same field name it gets ambiguous and to solve this
use SELECT`NEWS.id` or `TAGS.id` which table's `id` you are using:

```
"SELECT NEWS.id,title,front_thumbs,short_desc,timestamp,counter,author,
FROM " . NEWS . " LEFT JOIN " . TAGS . " ON " NEWS . ".id = " . TAGS .    ".content_id WHERE 
" . TAGS . ".tags_id = ? AND approved = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10", $id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need alias. Yuo have 2 tables both with column `id`. In your select you request `id` without specifying which of them you need.

You need to specify table here (before `id`):

`... ("SELECT id,title,front_thumbs,short ...`