# 2 SQL Server queries throw an error I cannot take mssql_fetch_array

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to take logged users last 200 rows OrderId's from `Orders` table

```
WHERE UserName = '$user' 
  AND OrderState = '1' 
  AND OrderId = OrderDetails
```

My tables here

**Orders**

```
OrderId int
UserName nvarchar(64)
OrderState int
```

**OrderDetails**

```
OrderId int
OrderDetailId int
```

My sample code:

```
$queryf = "SELECT TOP 200 * FROM Orders WHERE UserName='$user' AND OrderState='1' AND (SELECT * FROM OrderDetails WHERE OrderId='HERE PROBLEM') ORDER BY OrderId DESC";
$resultf = @mssql_query($queryf);
$sayif = @mssql_num_rows($resultf);

while($rowf = @mssql_fetch_array($resultf))
{
   $CustomerIds = $rowf["CustomerId"];
}
```

Another sample codes added from @vkp

```
    SELECT TOP 200 o.*
    FROM Orders o 
    JOIN OrderDetails d on o.OrderId = d.OrderId
    WHERE UserName='$user' 
      AND OrderState='1' 
    ORDER BY o.OrderId DESC
```

Throws an error

> [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'UserName'.

I'm trying but I don't know how to resolve it.

Thanks !

Comment: @HartCO codes dont work

Comment: @HartCO don't work codes added

Comment: how do you identify 1)logged users and 2)last 200 rows?

Comment: @vkp i added my sample codes  you can see there

Comment: @vkp gives   SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'UserName'. error

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?!

Comment: @eggyal if you know mysql query i convert my codes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638520/1052-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should be all you need:

```
Select  Distinct Top 200 O.*
From    Orders          O
Join    OrderDetails    D   On  O.OrderId = D.OrderId
Where   O.UserName = '$user'
And     O.OrderState = 1
Order By O.OrderId Desc
```

Another option is to use `EXISTS`:

```
Select  Top 200 O.*
From    Orders  O
Where   Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    OrderDetails    D
    Where   D.OrderId = O.OrderId
)
And     O.UserName = '$user'
And     O.OrderState = 1
Order By O.OrderId Desc
```

Comment: dude i checked now coming 4 rows with that OrderIds (1062293,1062293,1062293,1062295)  but must be only 2 row (1062293,1062295)

Comment: I had a typo in the query that I just corrected a few seconds ago - try the updated query in my answer.

Comment: yes same gives 4 rows must be different 2 rows only different OrderIds

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected results to the question?

Comment: Order ID = 1062293,1062289,1062289,1062289  OrderState = 1,1,1,1  UserName = ok,ok,ok,ok

Comment: Oh, hold on, I see the issue.  Try again with this query

Comment: gives SQL Server]The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: Try the second query - that one should work without a `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thanks man ! Very good ty a lot i think be help too many people