# Ambiguous column name customerid

Tags: sql-server, sql-scripts

I have a problem when I try to run this script I get the above error message. I am a rookie my level is beginner I am just trying to teach myself. What

This is my script

```
Select * 
from Customer, Account where customerid=8;
```

[This is my relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB7ec.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638520/1052-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous)

Comment: There is also a high likelihood of a poor query here. You have a cross join from customer to account. I doubt that is really what you want. You should really use the more current join syntax. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Perhaps supply the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `Customer` and `Account`?

Answer (score 0):

You customer and account both have `customerid` field

You need specify what table are you refering too

```
Select * 
from Customer, Account 
where Customer.customerid=8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because customerid appears in both tables you have to tell SQL which table you want to use, e.g.

```
Select *
from Customer, Account where Customer.customerid = 8
```

or

```
Select *
from Customer, Account where Account.customerid = 8
```