# SQL JOIN cant get it working

Tags: mysql, sql

I know the forum is full of this questions but i cant find the solution.
I want to join the table users from user_to_designment they both have a column with user_id the error that i get is:

```
select user_id, designment_id FROM user_to_designment
FULL JOIN users
ON  user_to_designment.user_id = users.user_id


 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL meldt: Documentatie

#1052 - Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous
```

I use this query:

```
select user_id, designment_id FROM user_to_designment
FULL JOIN users
ON  user_to_designment.user_id = users.user_id
```

Please some advice

Comment: What do you think the words in "Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous " mean?

Comment: Tip of today: table aliases!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638520/1052-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1):

In your select list prefix the user_id with the table name:

```
select users.user_id, designment_id FROM user_to_designment
FULL JOIN users
ON  user_to_designment.user_id = users.user_id
```

Both columns have user_id, SQL cannot choose between them, you must specify explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which user_id to return in your select, eg select users.user_id or Select user_to_designment.user_id

Answer (score 0):

You must clarify which user_id table column you are selecting.

```
select a.user_id,b.designment_id from user_to_designment b
full join users a
on b.user_id=a.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because "user_id" field exists on both tables.
you must put table name before field name.

```
    select user_to_designment.user_id, designment_id FROM user_to_designment
FULL JOIN users
ON  user_to_designment.user_id = users.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems user_id exist in both the tables. so it gives the ambiguous error. We should say from which table we have to pick the column.

```
SELECT users.user_id
    ,user_to_designment.designment_id
FROM user_to_designment
FULL JOIN users ON user_to_designment.user_id = users.user_id
```

You may use either users.user_id or user_to_designment.user_id in your select statement. Always use tablename.columnname format. It avoids confusion.