# How do I 'join' but keep things separate in tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join, having-clause

I have two tables. Table Employees:

```
EmployeeID (employees)  LastName (employees)    FirstName (employees)
1                       Davolio                 Nancy
```

---

And Table Orders:

```
OrderID (orders)    CustomerID (orders) EmployeeID (orders)
10248               90                  5
10278               45                  1
10238               47                  1
```

I redacted the full listing because it's hundreds of rows.

In the table Employees, the EmployeeID can uniquely identify an employee, meaning it will not repeat in the Employee table. However in the Table 'Order' The employeeID can repeat several times because an employee can sell help with many orders.

Anyway, I can see here that in the Orders table, an employeeID will repeat several times, which means I need to use COUNT(EmployeeID)>=2 somewhere in my MySQL code.

This is what I'd like:

```
EmployeeID              Number of Orders
1                       2
```

As you can see, the EmployeeID shows up twice in the "orders" table. So he sold 2 items, and it links to his 1 Employee ID.

So this is what I tried:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, COUNT(EmployeeID) FROM
employees A inner join 
orders B
ON (A.EmployeeID=B.EmployeeID)
WHERE COUNT(B.EmployeeID >=2)
```

This is the output:

Error: Column 'EmployeeID' in field list is ambiguous — ERROR CODE 1052

I'm not sure how I would get this result in this scenario.

Comment: The error basically means that it doesn't know which EmployeeID you mean in your select as it is in both employees and orders.  Changing it to A.EmployeeID would get rid of that error, but it also won't get the results as you want them, see the answer below.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf thanks for the explanation there. I had a feeling that's what "ambiguous" meant

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1052: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638520/1052-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous)

Comment: There is never a reason to be rude, even if you think someone else was. The "does this answer" is an automated comment (poorly phrased, complain to the company like the rest of us) posted when one flags a post as duplicate. However there is no justification for thinking it must be meant negatively. Also you have jumped to (wrong) (negative) conclusions not only about that. Re my profile looking like Strawberry's we both added a hashtag to an empty profile during a SO promotion. (You could have just googled it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to join with the `employees` table, you can get the employee ID from `orders`. You would only need to join if you also need other information from the `employee` table, such as their name.

You need `GROUP BY employeeID` to get a count for each employee.

`>= 2` should not be inside the `COUNT()` function, you want to compare the result.

You need to use `HAVING` rather than `WHERE`. `WHERE` is used to select the rows to process *before* aggregating.

You should use `COUNT(*)` rather than `COUNT(columnName)` unless you need to exclude null values of the column from the count.

If you give an alias to the `COUNT(*)` result, you can use that alias in the `HAVING` clause rather than restating the function.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, COUNT(*) AS number_of_orders
FROM orders B
GROUP BY EmployeeID
HAVING number_of_orders >= 2
```

The reason for your error about the ambiguous column is because both tables have `EmployeeID` columns. In the `SELECT` list you need to specify `A.EmployeeID` or `B.EmployeeID`, just as you did in the `ON` clause.

Comment: ...apart from that, it was spot on

Comment: thank you so much for the explantion! it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

You want to build groups of orders that belong to the same employee, and then filter on the count of rows per group. For this, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select employeeid, count(*) cnt_orders
from employees e 
inner join orders o using(employeeid)
group by employeeid
having count(*) >= 2
```

Note that a join is not necessary here. You can get the result you want directly from the table of orders:

```
select employeeid, count(*) cnt_orders
from orders 
group by employeeid
having count(*) >= 2
```