# How to use search query with join tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a database. The first table is "tb_ctsreport" with fields "qr_id, idNum, date, time" and the other one is "tb_usersreg" with many fields which includes idNum, firstName, lastName, age and address. I have displayed my table using this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_ctsreport LEFT JOIN tb_usersreg ON tb_ctsreport.idNum=tb_usersreg.idNum";
```

This gives me a resulting table of qr_id, idNum, Name(concatenated firstName and lastName), date, time.
Then I wanted to create a search query from this table that I have created, however, I am lost and I don't know how will I include the values firstName and lastName when searching because it is placed in another table. This is my working query except for an undefined index for displaying the name since I don't know how.

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_ctsreport WHERE CONCAT(qr_id, idNum, time, date) LIKE '%".$searchBox."%'";
```

I have also tried this sql query but only gives me an error.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_ctsreport WHERE CONCAT(qr_id, idNum, time, date) LIKE '%".$searchBox."%'  
UNION
SELECT * FROM tb_usersreg WHERE CONCAT(lastName, firstName) LIKE '%".$searchBox."%'";
```

Please help me. I am just new to php. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, you can use the `WHERE` clause after your `LEFT JOIN` like: `SELECT * FROM tb_ctsreport LEFT JOIN tb_usersreg ON tb_ctsreport.idNum=tb_usersreg.idNum WHERE CONCAT(qr_id, idNum, time, date, lastName, firstName) LIKE '%".$searchBox."%'`.

Also you have an [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Hi @homer It says mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given...

Comment: That means the query failed _in some way_, but doesn't tell you specifically how. Enable mysqli error reporting to get a better error message. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before you open your mysqli connection, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP.

Comment: @ADyson still gives me the same error. Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\IT3105\ctsReport.php on line 255

Comment: If you used it correctly, it would not do that. Make sure you add it _before_ you run `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: @ADyson it says Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Column 'idNum' in where clause is ambiguous'

Comment: Ok so that just means you need to specify which of the tables you want to take `idNum` from. For future reference... "column is ambiguous" is a standard SQL error which you can google and find the solution to easily. Most errors are google-able.

Comment: Yes I know. So what? Someone suggesting a query doesn't guarantee it would work exactly. You need to fix that error.

Comment: @ADyson what do you mean by specifying on which table?

Comment: @ADyson yes..sorry im just stating

Comment: Well presumably `tb_ctsreport` and `tb_usersreg` both contain columns called `idNum`. Which one do you want to use in your CONCAT statement? SQL doesn't know and can't guess, so you have to tell it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638520/1052-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous explains this error and how to resolve it.

Comment: @ADyson it finally worked. TYSM FOR UR HELP. GODBLESS :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `WHERE` clause after the `JOIN`s clauses. So you can write your SQL query as:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM tb_ctsreport
    LEFT JOIN tb_usersreg ON tb_ctsreport.idNum = tb_usersreg.idNum
  WHERE
    CONCAT(
      tb_ctsreport.qr_id,
      tb_ctsreport.idNum,
      tb_ctsreport.time,
      tb_ctsreport.date,
      tb_usersreg.lastName,
      tb_usersreg.firstName
    ) LIKE :searchBox
```

In the above query `:searchBox` is your query parameter.

Care when you concatenate user input with your SQL query, this introduces a huge security vulnerability called [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You shuld prefer to use parameterized query to avoid this issue.

When you are referencing multiple tables in an SQL query I advise you to always use the fully qualified name for the columns in order to avoid any ambiguity.