# Selecting using two column names, using the other one if one is known of each record

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this as a concise question title.

I have a `games` table which contains of records representing games of a player against another. The relevant columns of this table are `userid1` and `userid2`. I have another table called `accounts`, consisting of the columns `id` and `username`.

I'd like to fetch **the username of the opponent** from the `accounts` table. The opponent is the user of which the id is not equal to the known user id. So, if `userid1 = 123` then I'd like to fetch `accounts.username` of the user where `accounts.id` is equal to `userid2` of the same `games` record. The same goes the other way round if `userid2 = 123`.

I've so far only been able to select the opponent's username separately using two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM games, accounts
WHERE games.userid1 = 123 AND accounts.id = games.userid2
```

and:

```
SELECT * FROM games, accounts
WHERE games.userid2 = 123 AND accounts.id = games.userid1
(swapped:         ^                                     ^)
```

However, I'd like to combine these two queries nicely into one. So, is it possible to get `accounts.username` where `accounts.id` is equal to:

- `games.userid2` if `games.userid1` is equal to the known user id
- `games.userid1` if `games.userid2` is equal to the known user id

and if so, how?

Comment: @Mat: That does the trick just great. I'm trying to grasp the basics, forgive my ignorance...

Comment: [Implicit joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/) shouldn't be used in favor of [explicit joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a case statement in your join condition, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM games g
    JOIN accounts a 
      ON a.id = case g.userid1 when ? then g.userid2 else g.userid1 end
WHERE 
    g.userid1 = ? OR g.userid2 = ?
```

However, depending on your indexes, it may be quicker to use a union, eg.

```
  SELECT * FROM games g
      JOIN accounts a ON a.id = case g.userid2
  WHERE g.userid1 = ?
UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM games g
      JOIN accounts a ON a.id = case g.userid1
  WHERE g.userid2 = ?
```

An alternative query using `OR`,

```
SELECT * FROM games g, accounts a 
WHERE 
      (g.userid1 = ? AND g.userid2 = a.id) 
   OR (g.userid2 = ? AND g.userid1 = a.id)
```

Comment: The case statement works great, thanks. However, it seems `SELECT * FROM games, accounts WHERE games.userid2 = 123 AND accounts.id = games.userid1 OR games.userid1 = 123 AND accounts.id = games.userid2` (using Mat's suggestion) selects the same records. Is there possibly a difference between your solution and this one? This one seems a little bit more complex.

Comment: It looks like it will do the same. Ultimately, you need to test to ensure you are getting the data that you expect. And always look at the explain output especially if you will be running this over a large dataset.