# Correlated subquery mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1054

so i have a table with products

```
Product ID | Product Name
===========+===============
1          | Tissues
2          | Glass
```

I have a table with sales

```
Sale ID    | Product ID | Quantity | Price
===========+============+==========+=============
1          | 1          | 1        | 55
2          | 2          | 1        | 60
```

and i have a table of purchases

```
Batch ID | Total Value | Quantity | Product ID
=========+=============+==========+==================
1        | 100         | 100      | 1
2        | 10          | 50       | 2
3        | 1           | 1        | 2
```

So im trying to calculate the profit based on average cost using the query

```
SELECT tblsale.product_id, 
       tblproduct.product_name, 
       SUM(tblsale.`quantity`) qty,
       SUM(tblsale.`Price`*tblsale.`quantity`) sales, 
       (SELECT sum(total_value) / sum(quantity) VWAP 
        FROM tblpurchases 
        WHERE product_id = tblsale.product_id) average_price, 
       (average_price * qty) cost, 
       (sales-cost) profit 
FROM   tblsale, tblproduct 
WHERE tblproduct.product_id = tblsale.`product_id` 
GROUP by tblsale.`product_id`
```

But i can't seem to get it to work i get a 'average price' is an unknown column, how would I structure the query correctly

Comment: what is `Total Value` and `Quantity`?

Comment: Total value is the value of all the goods in the purchase and the quantity the number of units of the goods (so value/quantity) would be the average price of that particular batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL doesn't support referencing a column alias in the same SELECT clause - that's why your `average_price` column is returning the 1054 error.  You either have to do whatever operation you need in a subselect, derived table/inline view, or reuse the underlying logic where necessary.  Here's an example of the reuse of logic:

```
   SELECT prod.product_id, 
          prod.product_name, 
          SUM(s.quantity) qty,
          SUM(s.Price * s.quantity) sales, 
          SUM(pur.total_value) / SUM(pur.quantity) average_price, 
          SUM(pur.total_value) / SUM(pur.quantity) * SUM(s.quantity) cost, 
          SUM(s.Price * s.quantity) - (SUM(pur.total_value) / SUM(pur.quantity) * SUM(s.quantity)) profit 
     FROM tblproduct prod 
LEFT JOIN tblsale s ON prod.product_id = s.product_id
LEFT JOIN tblpurchases pur ON pur.product_id = prod.product_id
 GROUP BY s.product_id
```

My query is using ANSI-92 JOIN syntax, which I recommend over the ANSI-89 syntax your query uses.  See [this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/in-mysql-queries-why-use-join-instead-of-where).

Comment: Hmm, I was wondering. Does this run faster than having the inner select?

Comment: @MostyMostacho: Subselect performance depends - on most databases, scalar ones perform equally.  But others need to be checked, because they can execute row by row (not good).

Comment: Im getting a error 'GROUP BY s.product_id' at line 11' should the LEFT JOIN have an ON statement?

Comment: ON (pur.product_id = s.product_id) ?

Comment: You basically duplicated my answer, get the credits and I get `-1`. Something wrong here.

Comment: @Richard: There is no duplication - your answer uses a derived table/inline view, mine does not.  As I said in my answer, either is valid.  I don't feel that is enough to justify a downvote, personally.

Comment: @Akshat: Yes, sorry about that.  I've corrected it - thx for letting me know.

Comment: "your answer uses a derived table/inline view" - You're looking at the wrong answer then. You answer is 99% the same as mine and yours was posted hours later. You should have rather commented on my answer than duplicating it. I.m.h.o. the downvote was righteous.

Comment: @Richard: You've edited your answer, but it still admonishes the OP and doesn't explain why the error occurs.  Your answer had already been downvoted when I posted.  Your downvote is clearly not righteous, but a matter of sour grapes -- you'd rather lash out at me than assess the entire content of my answer.  I wonder if you're responsible for the other downvote I received today...

Answer (score -1):

How did you get to this query? It is completely off.. When writing a query, start small and then build it up. The query you have now is a complete mess and nowhere near to valid, there are random parenthesis' through out it.

To make a start, use indentation to make your query readable

```
    SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name
         , SUM(s.quantity) number_of_sales
         , SUM(s.price) total_profit
         , SUM(pu.quantity) purchase_quantity
         , SUM(pu.value) purchase_value
         , (SUM(pu.quantity) - SUM(s.quantity)) number_in_stock
         , (SUM(s.price) - SUM(pu.value)) profit
         , (SUM(pu.value) / SUM(pu.quantity)) avarage_purchase_price
      FROM product p
 LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.product_id = p.product_id
 LEFT JOIN purchase pu ON pu.product_id = p.product_id         
  GROUP BY s.product_id, pu.product_id
```

"*But i can't seem to get it to work i get a 'average price' is an unknown column, how would I structure the query correctly*"

What is 'average price'? How would you like average price to be calculated? And the same for 'average cost'

Comment: average cost and average price would be the same, average cost the weighted average cost of all the purchases on record