# Error in SQL syntax, check for right syntax to use near '0' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have meet the error mentioned in the title, here is the code in my PHP file, I have tried to reform my query, but fail to correct the error, can anyone tell me why there is such kind of error, is there the way I form the error is incorrect? I have seen some similar posts, but what I know from those posts is the problem should be my query, but I have no idea how to change it. So may I ask for your help to tell me where is the problem of my query, this can definitely help me to make clear my concept.

```
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM Tech AS T, Client AS C, Site AS S, Log AS L 
    WHERE T.TechID=L.TechID, C.ClientID=L.ClientID, S.SiteID=L.SiteID";
if($sort=="Tech")
   $query += "ORDER BY T.TechName ASC, L.Time DSC";
else if($sort=="Client")
   $query += "ORDER BY C.ClientName ASC, L.Time DSC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error! ' . mysql_error());; 
print "Real-Time check in/check out<br>";
print "<table><th><td>Tech</td><td>Client</td><td>Site</td>";
print "<td>Date and Time</td><td>Type</td></th>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
print "<tr><td>".$row['T.TechName']."</td>";
print "<td>".$row['C.ClientName']."</td>";
print "<td>".$row['S.SiteName']."</td>";
print "<td>".$row['L.Time']."</td>";
print "<td>".$row['L.Type']."</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Below is the error message:

> Error! You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1

Comment: Note that `or die(mysql_error())` should never appear in production code, as [`die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) breaks HTML output and database error messages should never be revealed to non-admin users as it [discloses too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2). A better approach would be to properly implement error handling (and use PDO instead of the outdated mysql extension, which is being deprecated).

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use a join here ? And I think you forgot to add spaces at your "ORDER BY" strings.

Comment: [Implicit joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/) shouldn't be used in favor of [explicit joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/).

Comment: Note that whenever you're generating an SQL statement and are getting a syntax error, you should get the actual statement generated (and post it), and not just the code that generates the statement.

Comment: SO uses a Q&A, rather than a forum, format. Questions shouldn't contain an answer, such as corrected code. Leave that to the answers.

Comment: For coding issues other than correctness issues, you should check out [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't see where a zero could be coming from..

But at the lines where you are appending the ORDER BY to your query you're missing a space.

Either append a space at the end of you original `$query`, or append a space to the beginning of your `$query +=`

Also for descending it should be `DESC` not `DSC`

Also the += should be a .= for PHP

Comment: oh I see, because I just follow the way like writing C++, so making such kind of careless error, sorry.

Comment: Always be sure to check the (minor) differences while switching languages ;)

Comment: may I ask why there still have error in the order by sentence after I switch it to desc? here is the error message "Error! You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T.TechName ASC, L.Time DESC' at line 3"

Comment: Ah sorry, you cant use ASC and DESC together, I believe. Just use DESC *OR* ASC at the end or your query

Comment: I think it is okay to do so, as when I change it like the code I given above, it gives out no problem now(at least it works now)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in the `WHERE` clause.  You need to use `AND` construct instead of commas:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tech AS T, Client AS C, Site AS S, Log AS L 
WHERE T.TechID=L.TechID AND C.ClientID=L.ClientID AND S.SiteID=L.SiteID
```

Yet, even a better solution would be to use a join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tech AS T
JOIN Client AS C on T.TechID=L.TechID
JOIN Site AS S on C.ClientID=L.ClientID
JOIN Log AS L on S.SiteID=L.SiteID
```

**EDIT:** You get `near 0 at line 1` because you use `+` trying concatenate strings instead of `.` operator.  When you use `+`, php converts both parts to numbers and adds them.  As your strings don't contact numbers, both are converted to 0 and thus the result is `0`.  Therefore your final SQL is simply `0`.  You could check it with `print_r($query);`

**EDIT2:** Thanks to Gerald Vesluis for noticing a missing space in the beginning of the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 3):

AND instead of commas,

space before `ORDER`

`.=` instead of `+=`

```
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM Tech AS T, Client AS C, Site AS S, Log AS L 
    WHERE T.TechID=L.TechID AND C.ClientID=L.ClientID AND S.SiteID=L.SiteID";
if($sort=="Tech")
   $query .= " ORDER BY T.TechName ASC, L.Time DESC";
else if($sort=="Client")
   $query .= " ORDER BY C.ClientName ASC, L.Time DESC";
```

Comment: OMG, I missed the += issue :s

Comment: @OlivierCoilland I did too at a first glance! Think it comes with working with different languages ;)

Comment: oh, and `DESC` instead of `DSC`

Answer (score 1):

[`+` and `+=`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) add numbers, [`.` and `.=`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) append strings.

Field names in the result array don't include the table name. You should reference (e.g.) `$row['TechName']`, not `$row['T.TechName']`.

#### Off Topic

Mixing DB access and output creates too high a coupling. Ideally, each would be handled in separate layers. You can start this process by using PDO or (in PHP 5.4 and greater) mysqli, and iterate with `foreach` over results instead of explicitly calling any methods that are a part of the DB results class interface. This magic is possible because [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/PDOStatement) and (as of PHP 5.4) [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/mysqli_result) support the [`Traversable`](http://php.net/Traversable) interface.

[`<br/>`](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/#br) is rarely [semantic](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html); use something more appropriate, such as a heading element, or apply styling to existing elements.

`<th>` isn't a valid parent of `<td>`; `<tr>` should be the parent and `<th>` should be used *in place of* `<td>`.

While brackets are optional when a branch consists of a single statement, it's usually considered bad style to leave them out, as it occasionally leads to bugs.

While `else if` is functionally equivalent to `elseif`, it's handled by the runtime as an `else` with an `if` as the body:

```
if (...) {
} else {
    if (...) {
    }
}
```

`elseif` is the preferred form.

If there's any chance that `$sort` could hold a non-string, `==` could evaluate to `TRUE` even (`0 == 'Tech'`). Use [strict comparison (`===`)](http://php.net/===) to ensure the values are compared as strings.

Apply the various suggested alterations and you'll wind up with something like:

```
# Future improvement: abstract each section into methods that are part of separate layers

# Database access
$statement = 'SELECT T.TechName, C.ClientName, S.SiteName, L.Time, L.Type 
    FROM Log AS L
      JOIN Tech AS T ON T.TechID=L.TechID
      JOIN Client AS C ON C.ClientID=L.ClientID
      JOIN Site AS S ON S.SiteID=L.SiteID';

if ($sort === 'Tech') {
   $query .= ' ORDER BY T.TechName ASC, L.Time DESC';
} elseif ($sort === 'Client') {
   $query .= ' ORDER BY C.ClientName ASC, L.Time DESC';
}

try {
    $data = $db->query($statement);
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    $data = array();
    # handle error appropriately: inform user that there was an internal error. Log the actual error and possibly notify the dev team.
    ...
}

# Output/User interface
$fields = array('TechName' => 'Tech', 'ClientName' => 'Client', 'SiteName' => 'Site', 'Time' => 'Date and Time', 'Type' => 'Type');
if ($data) {
    ?>
    <h3>Real-Time check in/check out</h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr><th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', $fields) ?></th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
          <tr>
            <?php foreach ($fields as $field => $label) { ?>
              <td><?php echo $row[$field] ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put a space at the end of $query because you are appending the order by statements onto it without any space between.

So it would look like this:

```
L.SiteIDORDERBY
```

Instead of like this:

```
L.SiteID ORDER BY
```