# Selecting from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm using this code:

```
SELECT *
  FROM admins, vips
  WHERE admins.Expired < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
    AND vips.Expired < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

I have 2 rows in first and 2 rows in second. But I only getting 2 rows in "vips" table. Why?

Comment: What is the relationship between the tables? You have no joining condition between them.

Comment: [Explicit joins](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2241991/) should be used in favor of [implicit joins](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44917/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the `*` for both tables, like this:

```
SELECT admins.*, vips.*
FROM admins, vips
WHERE admins.Expired < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
AND vips.Expired < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

EDIT: The answer above isn't going to help, you need a `UNION SELECT`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM vips
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM admins) derivedTable       -- this is an alias of the subquery
WHERE Expired < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Comment: This will make no difference.

Comment: Yeah I was re-reading the question, I misunderstood. Editing now

Comment: Thank You. The interesting thing is this works too:     SELECT * FROM admins, vips WHERE admins.Expired < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY

Comment: It probably didn't apply the WHERE to the vips.

Comment: your edit doesn't work too. mysql replied "Every derived table must have its own alias".

Comment: add an alias after the subquery eg `...(SELECT * FROM vips
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM admins) x`

Comment: thank you, but it's not work for me: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns. I has 2 columns more in one table(another columns are the same)