# mysql join clause equivalent where clauses and vice verse

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database

I want to replace my

```
SELECT *  FROM TABLE 1, TABLE 2
WHERE tbl1.aaa = tbl2.bbb
```

to replace something with join clause, and similar other replacements vice verse, is there a quick reference on this?

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as below.

```
SELECT *  FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.aaa = tbl2.bbb
```

References to learn about `JOIN`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Comment: @PhillipD, it must be ON missing, since USING requires same column names.

Comment: I know I just need a big reference on specifically replacing where statements to join statements.

Comment: This may help you to answer why you should use `JOIN` over `Where` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/in-mysql-queries-why-use-join-instead-of-where

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
SELECT *  
FROM TABLE 1 as tbl1 
JOIN TABLE 2 as tbl2
 on tbl1.aaa = tbl2.bbb
```

or

[read this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: "link-only answers" should be comments, not answers.