# SQL; Error Code: 1111 | needing to encapsulate AVG

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem:

1) I have successfully managed to create a result displaying JUST the revenues of multiple movies (count how often it was rented * the rental rate). [Example A]

2) Now I want to get the average of this.
I have managed to do it if I write another query around it [Example B], but I want to enclose it into the same query if possible. [Example C - which gives me an error]. Is this at all possible?

Example A:

```
SELECT  COUNT(r.rental_id) * f.rental_rate AS Revenue
        FROM film f, rental r, inventory i
        WHERE i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
            AND f.film_id = i.film_id
        GROUP BY f.title
        ORDER BY Revenue DESC
```

Example B: (How I could make it work - encapsulated query)

```
SELECT AVG(B.Revenue)
    FROM (

        SELECT  COUNT(r.rental_id) * f.rental_rate AS Revenue
        FROM film f, rental r, inventory i
        WHERE i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
            AND f.film_id = i.film_id
        GROUP BY f.title
        ORDER BY Revenue DESC ) B
```

Example C: (How i want it to work - one single query)

```
SELECT  AVG (COUNT(r.rental_id) * f.rental_rate) AS Revenue
        FROM film f, rental r, inventory i
        WHERE i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
            AND f.film_id = i.film_id
        GROUP BY f.title
        ORDER BY Revenue DESC
```

Example C gives: "Error Code: 1111 \n Invalid use of group function"

Comment: Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper, `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I actually looked that up an hour ago and found this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/in-mysql-queries-why-use-join-instead-of-where

Comment: You should rename the title, this has nothing to do with SVG, rather partially include the error message itself.

Comment: but perhaps you are right. Looks nicer anyways.  &done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error message carefully *Invalid use of group function*. Problem is in first line of your query as pointed below. You can't nest the group function the way you are trying. You will have to get that in a outer query.

```
AVG (COUNT(r.rental_id) * f.rental_rate)
```

Something like

```
SELECT AVG(Revenue) FROM (
SELECT  COUNT(r.rental_id) * f.rental_rate AS Revenue
        FROM film f
        JOIN inventory i ON f.film_id = i.film_id
        JOIN rental r ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
        GROUP BY f.title ) xxx
        ORDER BY Revenue DESC;
```