# mySQL Select from two tables and match result

Tags: mysql

I'd like to

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2 as t1
```

And i'd like to

```
SELECT column3 FROM table2 WHERE column4 = "1" AND column3 = (matches)t1.column1
```

How should my query look like?

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2 FROM table1 as t1,
column3 FROM table2 WHERE column4 = "1" AND column3 = t1.column1
```

The result should be a list with data from column1, that matches data from column3 AND column4 = 1

```
Table1:                Table2:
-----------------------------------------
column1    column2     column3    column4
-----------------------------------------
001        Name        001        1      
002        Name        002        0
003        Name        004        1
005        Name        005        1
-----------------------------------------
Result: 001, 005
```

Error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM table2 WHERE column4 =
>   '1' AND column3 = t1.column1' at line 1

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct
   t1.column1,
   t1.column2,
   t2.column4
from
   table1 as t1
inner join
   table2 as t2 on t2.column3 = t1.column1
where
   column4 = "1"
```

Comment: Thank you. Work's like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column3, t2.column4
FROM
    table1 AS t1,
    table2 AS t2
WHERE
    t2.column4 = '1'
        AND t2.column3 = t1.column1
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use this notation. A proper join should be used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/in-mysql-queries-why-use-join-instead-of-where

This notation is old and depricated.

Comment: This notation is called implicit join. It has been deprecated for long compared to the explicit join that allows you to do more than just an inner join