# What is the difference between FROM and CROSS JOIN in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE test2 (
    id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE test3 (
    id INTEGER
);
```

I insert 10 into `test1`, 10 and 20 into `test2`, 10, 20 and 30 into `test3` in the following way:

```
INSERT INTO test1 (id)
VALUES (10);
```

Then i try to retrieve the data in the following 2 ways:

the first way:

```
SELECT *
FROM test1, test2, test3;
```

the second way:

```
SELECT *
FROM test1
CROSS JOIN test2, test3;
```

In both ways i get the same result:

```
"10"    "10"    "10"
"10"    "10"    "20"
"10"    "10"    "30"
"10"    "20"    "10"
"10"    "20"    "20"
"10"    "20"    "30"
```

As i can see there is no difference, **so what for is there `CROSS JOIN` ?**

Comment: All your queries are cross joins; comma-delimited table syntax was deprecated over 30 years ago and replaced with modern *join* syntax, perhaps time to read some modern sql tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of what results they return, there *isn't* a difference.  [From the SQLite documentation:](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#special_handling_of_cross_join_)

> There is no difference between the "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" and "," join operators. They are completely interchangeable in SQLite. The "CROSS JOIN" join operator produces the same result as the "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" and "," operators, but is handled differently by the query optimizer in that it prevents the query optimizer from reordering the tables in the join.

Either way, you get the Cartesian product of the rows in the specified tables.

But stylistically, [explicitly using the `JOIN` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241991/in-mysql-queries-why-use-join-instead-of-where/2242015#2242015) makes the intent of the query more clear than the older comma join syntax.