# What's the whole point of writing CHECK constraints in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

The MySQL Reference Manual says:

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored
>   by all storage engines.

No mistake. I've read that over 10 times.

So what's the whole point of writing check constraints then?

Comment: The real question is: why does MySQL still not support them...

Comment: possible duplicate of [check constraint in mysql not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-not-working) and others

Answer (score 4):

It's there because of interoperability concerns. You can for example import an SQL script that is generated by other RDBMSs that support CHECK constraint (say Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

There is no point.
I think they prepared the database to accept check constraints by adding support for them in the SQL parser but none of the engines still support them.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a bug report for over 7 years.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464

Personal opinion: another reason not to use MySQL, like [NATURAL JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826613/natural-join-in-sql-server/4826659#4826659) (and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277580/27535)) and random aggregates