# Special Case of Natural Join

Tags: relational-algebra

What is the the result of natural join if two relations have exactly the same attributes? That is suppose

A B A B

1 2 7 8

3 4 9 10

5 6 1 2

Would the result just be

A B

1 2

Comment: Your answer is correct. For extra credit, what is the result of natural join if the two relations have *no* attributes in common?

Comment: The Cartesian product.

Comment: That's right. Product is just a special case of Natural Join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between a theta join, equijoin and natural join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870155/difference-between-a-theta-join-equijoin-and-natural-join)