# compute precision/recall curve in SQL

Tags: sql, machine-learning

Suppose I have classification decisions and confidences as records, is there any way to get precision/recall curve through SQL? In other words, is there a way to collapse the following set of queries into one?

```
select avg(predicted_label=correct_label) from t where confidence<0
select avg(predicted_label=correct_label) from t where confidence<1
select avg(predicted_label=correct_label) from t where confidence<2
select avg(predicted_label=correct_label) from t where confidence<3
select avg(predicted_label=correct_label) from t where confidence<4
select avg(predicted_label=correct_label) from t where confidence<5
select avg(predicted_label=correct_label) from t where confidence<6
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `avg` of `predicted_label` for ranges of confidence try this.
**EDIT**: Did a join on `<=`

```
SELECT FLOOR(t1.confidence), AVG(t2.predicted_label)
FROM Table t1
    JOIN Table t2 ON t2.confidence <= t1.Confidence
GROUP BY FLOOR(t1.confidence)
```

Comment: Interesting, wasn't over of "join on a<=b" syntax, which engines support that?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov AFAIK all db engines support such joins. Make sure the comparison column is indexed for better performance. Here is an [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25016_08/doc/dl/bi/B13916_04/joins.htm#i1014451) reference. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870155/difference-between-a-theta-join-equijoin-and-natural-join) might help.

Comment: I see. It doesn't seem to be in Google Cloud SQL (yet)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table (let's call it `numbers` with single column `num`) containing the relevant numbers from 0 to some large enough number, then you can simply say:

```
select avg(t.predicted_label=t.correct_label) 
  from t join numbers on t.confidence < numbers.num
 where numbers.num < 100 -- or whatever makes sense
group by numbers.num
```