# Trying to use dynamic SQL for join column names in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008, I would like to specify the column names of an inner join using dynamic SQL.  The two tables I am joining have the same names for the columns I am joining on.  I know SQL Server does not support natural joins; if it did, the dynamic SQL would look like something like this:

```
DECLARE @join_columns   AS NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @sql_1          AS NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @join_columns = 'Age, Gender' 

SET @sql_1 = '
    SELECT ' + @join_columns + ', table_1.Field_x , table_2.Field_y
    FROM table_1 , table_2
    NATURAL JOIN ON ' + @join_columns

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_1
```

Now, I realize this won't work because there are [no natural joins in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826613/natural-join-in-sql-server). So, what is the next best way to do this?

Here are a few things I unsuccessfully pursued:

- Tokenizing `@join_columns` and forming up a dynamic `WHERE table_1.<col_1> = table_2.<col_1> [AND...]` kind of clause. But, it doesn't look like T-SQL has string tokenization functions.
- Using dynamic SQL to make temp tables, each with a new key column called `temp_key` that is the concatenation of the fields in `@join_column`. If it were easy to dynamically concatenate these, then the final join could be always be `ON #temp_table_1.temp_key = #temp_table_2.temp_key`.  One way of setting this up would be to use the `REPLACE` function to replace the commas in `@join_column` with plus signs.  The problem I ran into here was that the concatenation required casting for the non-`VARCHAR` columns.  So, I'd have to know column types ahead of time - back to square one.

Ideally, I'd like to keep `@join_columns` as a comma-delimited string, because I am using it elsewhere in dynamic SQL `GROUP BY` clauses.

It may be that one of the failed approaches above could work, using something I missed.  Or, maybe there's a better overall approach.

Any suggestions?

### Update

Solution was a combination of both  @usr and @Karl's posts below.  I used @usr's suggestion to track down a tokenizing table-valued UDF (ended up going with [this one](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/sql_server_blog/136/string-tokenizer-for-sql-server-2008-written-in-tsql/) ). Then I used @Karl's `COALESCE` example to turn the resulting table into the `WHERE` clause.  I also used @Karl's full example for another join problem I just ran into.  I wish I could give answer status to both posters - thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that this works well:

```
declare @whereClause varchar(8000)
declare @table2 varchar(255)
declare @table1 varchar(255)

set @table1='SomeTable'
set @table2 = 'SomeOtherTable'

SELECT  COLUMN_NAME as [joincolumn]
into    #join_columns
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = @table1
AND COLUMN_NAME not in ('list names of columns that are not to be joined on here')

select @whereClause=coalesce(@whereClause+' and ','')+ 
'['+@table2+'].'+joincolumn+'=['+@table1+'].'+joincolumn +'
'
from #join_columns

print @whereClause
```

You can then create a dynamic SQL script and tag the WHERE clause to the back of it

Comment: This solves it.  There are too many columns to not join on, so I'll use tokenizing to get the table.  But I wasn't sure how to build the `WHERE` clause from the table till you presented this `COALESCE` example.  Also, I just found another use for the metadata stuff you showed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the tokenization/splitting functionality in a table valued UDF. That allows you to build the dynamic SQL string in a clean and architecturally sound way. You can find such splitting functions readily available on the web. It is a shame that they are not built-in but we can build them ourselves.

Comment: I did find a few, you're right.  That may be the route to go down.