# Are there any succinct approaches to this left join?

Tags: sql

A simple inner join

```
select * from table1 a
inner join 
dbo.table2 b
on a.inventory_id = b.inventory_id
```

Wouldn't it be nice and intuitive to put it like this?

```
select * from table1 a
inner join 
dbo.table2 b
on inventory_id
```

Are there any comparable succinct approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope that the `SELECT *` is for illustration, and not used in practice.

Comment: It would only be succinct if both key fields were named the same.  I'd rather spell them out then if I need to change them in the future I don't need to change the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a natural join:

```
select *
from table1 a
natural join dbo.table2 b
```

However, your RDBMS may not support it, and I would recommend always specifying the join type and conditions in your queries. It's much more maintainable in the long run.

I'm guessing from the `dbo.` that you're using SQL Server though, and it's not supported there. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826659/1121833) for more info.

**Edit:**
There's another possibility that's again not supported by SQL Server but is worth noting. This could actually be worth using, as your join condition is clearly specified. More info [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0140__Table-Joins/SimplifyingJoinswiththeUSINGKeyword.htm).

```
select *
from table1
inner join dbo.table2 using (inventory_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were using PostgreSQL, MySQL or Oracle, you can use a [Natural Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join)

```
   select *
     from table1 a
  natural join table2 b
```

Not sure why the question title includes "left", but you can do a `natural left join` as well.

Unfortunately, I'm sure you're using SQL Server due to the `dbo.`, so no, the `ON` condition is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ANSI standard `JOIN`s, then use implicit syntax:

```
select * from table1 a, table2 b
where a.inventory_id = b.inventory_id
```