# Natural Join in related table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to use only to use natural join 
it is not working in sql server,,, i have to select EmpName,EmpDOB and EMPDOB from employee table and just DEPTID from department table..please help

```
SELECT     DEPARTMENT.DEPTID, EMPLOYEE.EmpID, EMPLOYEE.EMPName, EMPLOYEE.EMPDOB
FROM         DEPARTMENT NATURAL JOIN
                      EMPLOYEE ON DEPARTMENT.DEPTID = EMPLOYEE.DEPTID
```

Comment: Hint:  a natural join doesn't need to specify the columns used in the join.

Comment: Why use a Natural Join? Seems like an Inner Join would do just as well and is a normal kind of join.

Comment: i am doing homework so i must use natural join..i am stuck i have tried alot

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` won't work with an `ON` statement.  No need to specify what fields are being joined, `NATURAL` takes care of that for you.

Comment: please send this to your teacher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826613/natural-join-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the '=' sign it is just a normal equi-join (explicit) while a natural join the predicates are figured out by the query engine (implicit). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Natural_join

Comment: Yeah, that would work just as easily, but it looks like, for the purposes of the assignment, he HAS to use a natural join.

Comment: i have tried this also and it is giving Syntax error near department SELECT *
FROM employee NATURAL JOIN department;

Answer (score 3):

If you must use a `NATURAL JOIN` then try this:

```
SELECT D.DEPTID, E.EmpID, E.EMPName, E.EMPDOB
FROM DEPARTMENT D NATURAL JOIN EMPLOYEE E
```

As long as the column names `DEPTID` are the SAME on both tables.  `NATURAL JOIN` Doesn't need to specify what fields are joined, it figures it out on it's own.

Here's a great reference on the `NATURAL JOIN`:
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/natural-join.php

The Natural Join won't work in SQL-Server though, only in MySQL.

Comment: i am doing homework..i am supposed to use Natural join ..please helpp

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: SQL SERVER two thousand eight

Answer (score 3):

SQL-Server has not implemented `NATURAL JOIN`.

If you want to experiment with its use, try Oracle or Postgres or MySQL. You can also use **[SQLfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/)** if you are not allowed to install them.