# How to display a specific range of numbers in an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, sqlitestudio

So there's just a little bit more to this than the title suggests. I've got a table which contains a **name** column and a **qty** column, I want to display the results who have a TOTAL sum qty between 500 and 1500.

Example:

```
name     qty
------  ----
brad     100
cody     300
kylie   1100
brad     800
nelson  1200
bob      600
nelson   100
kylie    600
```

I want the result to display

```
name     qty
------  ----
brad     900
nelson  1300
bob      600
```

Hopefully that makes sense. This is the query I've got

```
SELECT name, SUM(qty) AS Total 
FROM t1 
    NATURAL JOIN t2 
WHERE qty BETWEEN 500 AND 1500 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY name
```

The issue is that it seems to only be summing the fields in **qty** that are between 500 and 1500, rather than display only the **Total** fields that are in that range. I tried doing "WHERE SUM(qty) BETWEEN...." but this results in a compilation error (i'm using SQLite studio)

This is a homework problem for a database class I'm in, I'm looking to learn, not just get the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Bacon Bits, looks much cleaner now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for the join and you need to add a HAVING clause

```
SELECT name, SUM(qty) AS Total 
FROM t1 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING SUM(qty) BETWEEN 500 AND 1500
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HAVING clause, which is evaluated after aggregate functions like SUM:

```
SELECT name
    ,SUM(qty) AS Total 
FROM t1 
NATURAL JOIN t2 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING SUM(qty) BETWEEN 500 AND 1500
ORDER BY name
```

I'd also recommend against NATURAL JOIN.  It's [generally considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826613/natural-join-in-sql-server/4826659#4826659) because it introduces a point of error for no good return.

Comment: t1 contains the **name** column and an **id** column, and t2 has the **qty** column and **id** column. The id is the commonality that links the qty to a specific name. Without doing a NATURAL JOIN, what would be the better way for me to do it?

Comment: @dks209 Explicitly specify the JOIN condition: `FROM t1 NATURAL JOIN t2` becomes `FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id`.