# Alias of second joined tables

Tags: sql

I'm wondering how to make an alias for a combination of double joined tables. 
So, the question is TableOne natural join TableTwo and then join TableThree with `AID=AbID`, and I'd like to give this combined table an alias like NewTable. 
I tried:

```
((TableOne NATURAL JOIN TableTwo) JOIN TableThree ON (AID = AbID) AS NewTable
```

but seems not working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52790526/edit) link under your question to edit it, and provide the SQL code you are stuck in.

Comment: Please tag with the correct database that you are using. That query does not looks like a `SQL Server` query

Comment: SQL-Server does not have a `Natural Join` clause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826613/natural-join-in-sql-server

Comment: `natural join` is usually a good candidate for a join to avoid using. Later adding e.g. a CreatedDate to each table will silently stop your app working properly

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) give each table an alias when joining it:

```
 ((TableOne t1
   NATURAL JOIN TableTwo t2)
   JOIN TableThree t3
      ON (AID = AbID) AS NewTable
```

#### See also

[SQL Table Alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL))

Comment: Thanks for answering! However, it returns could not set relation alias "NewTable" because of ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

First, just don't use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is really broken, because it uses columns with the same *name* rather than properly declared foreign key relationships.  It also makes the code really hard to debug.  So use `ON` or `USING` instead.

Second, you can only do what you want with a subquery:

```
FROM . . . 
     (SELECT . . .               -- fill in with the columns you want
      FROM TableOne t1 JOIN
           TableTwo t2
           USING ( . . . ) JOIN  -- fill in with the columns used for the `JOIN`
           TableThree t3
           ON ?.AID = ?.AbID     -- fill in with the table aliases where the columns come from
     ) NewTable
```