# Natural Joins Vs Where Clauses

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is NATURAL JOIN any better than SELECT FROM WHERE in terms of performance ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063107/is-natural-join-any-better-than-select-from-where-in-terms-of-performance)

Is there an advantage to using natural joins vs a straight where clause in terms of SQL Server performance?  I don't see it, but I'm wondering what the advantage is other than separation of join logic and filtering.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as NATURAL JOIN in SQL Server (a [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826613/natural-join-in-sql-server/4826659#4826659) thing or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277580/27535))

If you mean explicit INNER JOIN syntax, then there is no performance difference

For more reasons why explicit is *good*, see my answer here
 [SQL JOIN: is there a difference between USING, ON or WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where/5654338#5654338)

Answer (score 0):

In short no - it's down to personal preference

Comment: Personal preference shouldn't come into it. Correctness should: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where/5654338#5654338