# the different between join condition and where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Somebody tell me what's the difference between two queries:

### Version A

```
select p.LastName, o.OrderNo  
  from Persons p, Orders o  
 where p.P_Id = o.P_Id
```

...and...

### Version B

```
select p.LastName, o.OrderNo  
  from Persons p 
  join Orders o on p.P_Id = o.P_Id
```

Comment: Dup:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/121631/144496

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both use an INNER JOIN to combine records between the PERSONS and ORDERS tables.  Version A is ANSI-89 syntax, and Version B is ANSI-92 syntax.

There's no performance difference between them, but the ANSI-92 syntax supports OUTER JOINs (LEFT, RIGHT, and FULL depending on the database) while the ANSI-89 does not.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that "join" is a shorthand syntax for "inner join" i see no difference.