# Select in SQL with id parameter

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table in sql, I use this statement to make a select:

```
SELECT id, name, genre FROM table
```

Now `genre` is id (int) and I have table called Genres and there I have :

```
id (int)
name (string)
```

What select will give me in genre the name and not the id.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What SQL do you have so far, and what results does that give you?

Comment: I'm hesitating whether what I imagine should be entered as an answer or not. It's certainly unclear what you want to ask.

Comment: Oh well some questions: What DB are you querying? What code did you use to execute the query? Can you already write a query on the DB console that gives you the desired result?

Comment: What's the relation of your question with C#?

Comment: **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, g.name 
FROM table t 
   JOIN genres g ON t.genre = g.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, g.name
FROM table t, genres g
WHERE t.genre = g.id
```

Comment: This does the same as [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10267007/578288), but is far slower. In general, `JOIN`s are faster than a Cartesian Product and a `WHERE`. At least, I learned that in [Database Systems class](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~jsalvage/Winter2012/CS461/index.html), but I don't remember the explanation behind it.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane No, it doesn't make any difference. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where

Comment: You're right. I asked my professor about that, and he said he didn't mean that `WHERE` was slower. It was just for teaching purposes that he wanted us to avoid `WHERE` syntax, because it can only be used to do an *inner* join. He wanted us to learn the syntax for `INNER JOIN` instead so that it would be easier to later teach us `OUTER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, etc., which have the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
 select G.name 
    from table table1 T,Genres G
    where T.genre = G.id;
```