# How was `outer` used in Informix-flavored SQL?

Tags: sql, informix

I've inherited some `<cough>`ugly`</cough>` code that contains a rather unwieldy SQL statement that hits an Informix database.  This code computes various parts of the SQL, and does lots of string concatenation, but I had it spit out what it actually sends to Informix and tried using that in my SQL query tool.  It is functional when it runs on the server, but when I try running it in FlySpeed SQL (which is an "approved" tool for use at the office), it complains about `outer` as an unknown keyword.  Googling got me nowhere, so I guessed this was an Informix shortcut for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but replacing it with that did nothing to fix the problem, so I'm guessing it's just a bug in FlySpeed.

The SQL is completely unformatted, which I'm guessing is part of what is tripping up FlySpeed.

```
SELECT A.CRSPD_SETID, A.CRSPD_CUST_ID, F.ST_ID_NUM as STMT_NBR, F.ST_DT, A.BUSINESS_UNIT, H.ASOF_DT, H.DUE_DT, A.ITEM, H.CONTRACT_NUM, D.DESCR as ENTRY_TYPE_DESCR, G.DESCR as ENTRY_REASON_DESCR, SUM(A.BAL_AMT) as ORIG_BAL_AMT, SUM(H.BAL_AMT), C.NAME1, B.ADDRESS1, B.ADDRESS2, B.ADDRESS3, B.ADDRESS4, B.CITY, B.STATE, B.POSTAL, A.BAL_CURRENCY, A.CUST_ID, A.ENTRY_TYPE as ORIG_ENTRY_TYPE, CASE WHEN A.ENTRY_TYPE = 'PY' OR A.ENTRY_TYPE = 'BGB' THEN 'AA' || substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3) ELSE  substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3) END, A.ENTRY_REASON as ORIG_ENTRY_REASON, C.CUSTOMER_TYPE, K.AR_LVL, H.ORDER_NO FROM PS_STMT_CUST_DTL A, PS_CUST_ADDRESS B, PS_CUSTOMER C, PS_SET_CNTRL_REC E, PS_STMT_CUST F, PS_ENTRY_TYPE_TBL D, PS_ENTRY_REASN_TBL G, outer PS_ITEM H, outer PS_BI_TYPE K WHERE A.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM AND B.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_CUST_ADDRESS B_ED Where B.SETID = B_ED.SETID AND B.CUST_ID = B_ED.CUST_ID AND B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = B_ED.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM AND B_ED.EFFDT <=  '06/19/2013') AND A.CRSPD_SETID = B.SETID AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = B.CUST_ID AND B.SETID = C.SETID AND B.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID AND B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = C.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM AND G.ENTRY_TYPE = A.ENTRY_TYPE AND G.ENTRY_REASON = A.ENTRY_REASON AND G.SETID = E.SETID AND G.SETID = D.SETID AND G.ENTRY_TYPE = D.ENTRY_TYPE AND E.SETCNTRLVALUE = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND E.RECNAME = 'ENTRY_TYPE_TBL' AND A.CRSPD_SETID = F.CRSPD_SETID AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = F.CRSPD_CUST_ID AND A.ST_ID_NUM = F.ST_ID_NUM AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = H.BUSINESS_UNIT AND A.CUST_ID = H.CUST_ID AND A.ITEM = H.ITEM AND A.ITEM_LINE = H.ITEM_LINE AND substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3) = K.BILL_TYPE_ID AND K.SETID = 'SPN' AND K.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(C_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_BI_TYPE C_ED WHERE K.SETID = C_ED.SETID AND K.BILL_TYPE_ID = C_ED.BILL_TYPE_ID AND C_ED.EFFDT <=  '06/19/2013') AND K.EFF_STATUS = 'A' AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID =  '000331' AND A.CRSPD_SETID = 'SPN' AND F.ST_DT = '' AND F.ST_ID_NUM = '' GROUP BY A.CRSPD_SETID, A.CRSPD_CUST_ID, F.ST_ID_NUM, F.ST_DT, A.BUSINESS_UNIT ,H.ASOF_DT, H.DUE_DT, A.ITEM, H.CONTRACT_NUM, D.DESCR, G.DESCR, C.NAME1 ,B.ADDRESS1, B.ADDRESS2, B.ADDRESS3, B.ADDRESS4, B.CITY, B.STATE ,B.POSTAL, A.BAL_CURRENCY, A.CUST_ID, A.ENTRY_TYPE ,25, A.ENTRY_REASON, C.CUSTOMER_TYPE, K.AR_LVL, H.ORDER_NO UNION ALL  SELECT A.CRSPD_SETID, A.CRSPD_CUST_ID, F.ST_ID_NUM as STMT_NBR, F.ST_DT, A.BUSINESS_UNIT, H.ASOF_DT, H.DUE_DT, A.ITEM, H.CONTRACT_NUM, D.DESCR as ENTRY_TYPE_DESCR, G.DESCR as ENTRY_REASON_DESCR, SUM(A.BAL_AMT) as ORIG_BAL_AMT, SUM(H.BAL_AMT), C.NAME1, B.ADDRESS1, B.ADDRESS2, B.ADDRESS3, B.ADDRESS4, B.CITY, B.STATE, B.POSTAL, A.BAL_CURRENCY, A.CUST_ID, A.ENTRY_TYPE as ORIG_ENTRY_TYPE, CASE WHEN A.ENTRY_TYPE = 'PY' OR A.ENTRY_TYPE = 'BGB' THEN 'AA' || substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3) ELSE  substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3) END, A.ENTRY_REASON as ORIG_ENTRY_REASON, C.CUSTOMER_TYPE, K.AR_LVL, H.ORDER_NO FROM PS_AR_STMT_CUSDT_H A, PS_CUST_ADDRESS B, PS_CUSTOMER C, PS_SET_CNTRL_REC E, PS_AR_STMT_CUST_H F, PS_ENTRY_TYPE_TBL D, PS_ENTRY_REASN_TBL G, outer PS_AR_ITEM_H H, outer PS_BI_TYPE K WHERE A.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM AND B.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_CUST_ADDRESS B_ED Where B.SETID = B_ED.SETID AND B.CUST_ID = B_ED.CUST_ID AND B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = B_ED.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM AND B_ED.EFFDT <=  '06/19/2013') AND A.CRSPD_SETID = B.SETID AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = B.CUST_ID AND B.SETID = C.SETID AND B.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID AND B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = C.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM AND G.ENTRY_TYPE = A.ENTRY_TYPE AND G.ENTRY_REASON = A.ENTRY_REASON AND G.SETID = E.SETID AND G.SETID = D.SETID AND G.ENTRY_TYPE = D.ENTRY_TYPE AND E.SETCNTRLVALUE = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND E.RECNAME = 'ENTRY_TYPE_TBL' AND A.CRSPD_SETID = F.CRSPD_SETID AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = F.CRSPD_CUST_ID AND A.ST_ID_NUM = F.ST_ID_NUM AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = H.BUSINESS_UNIT AND A.CUST_ID = H.CUST_ID AND A.ITEM = H.ITEM AND A.ITEM_LINE = H.ITEM_LINE AND substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3) = K.BILL_TYPE_ID AND K.SETID = 'SPN' AND K.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(C_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_BI_TYPE C_ED WHERE K.SETID = C_ED.SETID AND K.BILL_TYPE_ID = C_ED.BILL_TYPE_ID AND C_ED.EFFDT <=  '06/19/2013') AND K.EFF_STATUS = 'A' AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID =  '000331' AND A.CRSPD_SETID = 'SPN' AND F.ST_DT = '' AND F.ST_ID_NUM = '' GROUP BY A.CRSPD_SETID, A.CRSPD_CUST_ID, F.ST_ID_NUM, F.ST_DT, A.BUSINESS_UNIT ,H.ASOF_DT, H.DUE_DT, A.ITEM, H.CONTRACT_NUM, D.DESCR, G.DESCR, C.NAME1 ,B.ADDRESS1, B.ADDRESS2, B.ADDRESS3, B.ADDRESS4, B.CITY, B.STATE ,B.POSTAL, A.BAL_CURRENCY, A.CUST_ID, A.ENTRY_TYPE ,25, A.ENTRY_REASON, C.CUSTOMER_TYPE, K.AR_LVL, H.ORDER_NO ORDER BY 2,3,4,25,8,11,24
```

Am I correct that `OUTER` is just shorthand (maybe Informix-flavored shorthand) for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

***UPDATE***: I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251751/which-join-syntax-is-better#comment14791950_11251836) that Informix *did* in fact use `OUTER`, but I've yet to find any explanation of just *how*.  Obviously search results overwhelmingly favor things containing the normal syntax.  Even [this very useful RDBMS comparison](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/) contains almost nothing about Informix.

Here's the formatted SQL (sorry about the size!):

```
SELECT A.CRSPD_SETID,
       A.CRSPD_CUST_ID,
       F.ST_ID_NUM AS STMT_NBR,
       F.ST_DT,
       A.BUSINESS_UNIT,
       H.ASOF_DT,
       H.DUE_DT,
       A.ITEM,
       H.CONTRACT_NUM,
       D.DESCR AS ENTRY_TYPE_DESCR,
       G.DESCR AS ENTRY_REASON_DESCR,
       SUM(A.BAL_AMT) AS ORIG_BAL_AMT,
       SUM(H.BAL_AMT),
       C.NAME1,
       B.ADDRESS1,
       B.ADDRESS2,
       B.ADDRESS3,
       B.ADDRESS4,
       B.CITY,
       B.STATE,
       B.POSTAL,
       A.BAL_CURRENCY,
       A.CUST_ID,
       A.ENTRY_TYPE AS ORIG_ENTRY_TYPE,
       CASE
           WHEN A.ENTRY_TYPE = 'PY'
                OR A.ENTRY_TYPE = 'BGB' THEN 'AA' || substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3)
           ELSE substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3)
       END,
       A.ENTRY_REASON AS ORIG_ENTRY_REASON,
       C.CUSTOMER_TYPE,
       K.AR_LVL,
       H.ORDER_NO
FROM PS_STMT_CUST_DTL A,
     PS_CUST_ADDRESS B,
     PS_CUSTOMER C,
     PS_SET_CNTRL_REC E,
     PS_STMT_CUST F,
     PS_ENTRY_TYPE_TBL D,
     PS_ENTRY_REASN_TBL G,
     OUTER PS_ITEM H,
           OUTER PS_BI_TYPE K
WHERE A.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
  AND B.EFFDT =
    (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT)
     FROM PS_CUST_ADDRESS B_ED
     WHERE B.SETID = B_ED.SETID
       AND B.CUST_ID = B_ED.CUST_ID
       AND B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = B_ED.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
       AND B_ED.EFFDT <= '06/19/2013')
  AND A.CRSPD_SETID = B.SETID
  AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = B.CUST_ID
  AND B.SETID = C.SETID
  AND B.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
  AND B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = C.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
  AND G.ENTRY_TYPE = A.ENTRY_TYPE
  AND G.ENTRY_REASON = A.ENTRY_REASON
  AND G.SETID = E.SETID
  AND G.SETID = D.SETID
  AND G.ENTRY_TYPE = D.ENTRY_TYPE
  AND E.SETCNTRLVALUE = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
  AND E.RECNAME = 'ENTRY_TYPE_TBL'
  AND A.CRSPD_SETID = F.CRSPD_SETID
  AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = F.CRSPD_CUST_ID
  AND A.ST_ID_NUM = F.ST_ID_NUM
  AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = H.BUSINESS_UNIT
  AND A.CUST_ID = H.CUST_ID
  AND A.ITEM = H.ITEM
  AND A.ITEM_LINE = H.ITEM_LINE
  AND substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3) = K.BILL_TYPE_ID
  AND K.SETID = 'SPN'
  AND K.EFFDT =
    (SELECT MAX(C_ED.EFFDT)
     FROM PS_BI_TYPE C_ED
     WHERE K.SETID = C_ED.SETID
       AND K.BILL_TYPE_ID = C_ED.BILL_TYPE_ID
       AND C_ED.EFFDT <= '06/19/2013')
  AND K.EFF_STATUS = 'A'
  AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = '000331'
  AND A.CRSPD_SETID = 'SPN'
  AND F.ST_DT = ''
  AND F.ST_ID_NUM = ''
GROUP BY A.CRSPD_SETID,
         A.CRSPD_CUST_ID,
         F.ST_ID_NUM,
         F.ST_DT,
         A.BUSINESS_UNIT ,
         H.ASOF_DT,
         H.DUE_DT,
         A.ITEM,
         H.CONTRACT_NUM,
         D.DESCR,
         G.DESCR,
         C.NAME1 ,
         B.ADDRESS1,
         B.ADDRESS2,
         B.ADDRESS3,
         B.ADDRESS4,
         B.CITY,
         B.STATE ,
         B.POSTAL,
         A.BAL_CURRENCY,
         A.CUST_ID,
         A.ENTRY_TYPE ,
         25,
         A.ENTRY_REASON,
         C.CUSTOMER_TYPE,
         K.AR_LVL,
         H.ORDER_NO
UNION ALL
SELECT A.CRSPD_SETID,
       A.CRSPD_CUST_ID,
       F.ST_ID_NUM AS STMT_NBR,
       F.ST_DT,
       A.BUSINESS_UNIT,
       H.ASOF_DT,
       H.DUE_DT,
       A.ITEM,
       H.CONTRACT_NUM,
       D.DESCR AS ENTRY_TYPE_DESCR,
       G.DESCR AS ENTRY_REASON_DESCR,
       SUM(A.BAL_AMT) AS ORIG_BAL_AMT,
       SUM(H.BAL_AMT),
       C.NAME1,
       B.ADDRESS1,
       B.ADDRESS2,
       B.ADDRESS3,
       B.ADDRESS4,
       B.CITY,
       B.STATE,
       B.POSTAL,
       A.BAL_CURRENCY,
       A.CUST_ID,
       A.ENTRY_TYPE AS ORIG_ENTRY_TYPE,
       CASE
           WHEN A.ENTRY_TYPE = 'PY'
                OR A.ENTRY_TYPE = 'BGB' THEN 'AA' || substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3)
           ELSE substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3)
       END,
       A.ENTRY_REASON AS ORIG_ENTRY_REASON,
       C.CUSTOMER_TYPE,
       K.AR_LVL,
       H.ORDER_NO
FROM PS_AR_STMT_CUSDT_H A,
     PS_CUST_ADDRESS B,
     PS_CUSTOMER C,
     PS_SET_CNTRL_REC E,
     PS_AR_STMT_CUST_H F,
     PS_ENTRY_TYPE_TBL D,
     PS_ENTRY_REASN_TBL G,
     OUTER PS_AR_ITEM_H H,
           OUTER PS_BI_TYPE K
WHERE A.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
  AND B.EFFDT =
    (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT)
     FROM PS_CUST_ADDRESS B_ED
     WHERE B.SETID = B_ED.SETID
       AND B.CUST_ID = B_ED.CUST_ID
       AND B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = B_ED.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
       AND B_ED.EFFDT <= '06/19/2013')
  AND A.CRSPD_SETID = B.SETID
  AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = B.CUST_ID
  AND B.SETID = C.SETID
  AND B.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
  AND B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = C.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
  AND G.ENTRY_TYPE = A.ENTRY_TYPE
  AND G.ENTRY_REASON = A.ENTRY_REASON
  AND G.SETID = E.SETID
  AND G.SETID = D.SETID
  AND G.ENTRY_TYPE = D.ENTRY_TYPE
  AND E.SETCNTRLVALUE = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
  AND E.RECNAME = 'ENTRY_TYPE_TBL'
  AND A.CRSPD_SETID = F.CRSPD_SETID
  AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = F.CRSPD_CUST_ID
  AND A.ST_ID_NUM = F.ST_ID_NUM
  AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = H.BUSINESS_UNIT
  AND A.CUST_ID = H.CUST_ID
  AND A.ITEM = H.ITEM
  AND A.ITEM_LINE = H.ITEM_LINE
  AND substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3) = K.BILL_TYPE_ID
  AND K.SETID = 'SPN'
  AND K.EFFDT =
    (SELECT MAX(C_ED.EFFDT)
     FROM PS_BI_TYPE C_ED
     WHERE K.SETID = C_ED.SETID
       AND K.BILL_TYPE_ID = C_ED.BILL_TYPE_ID
       AND C_ED.EFFDT <= '06/19/2013')
  AND K.EFF_STATUS = 'A'
  AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = '000331'
  AND A.CRSPD_SETID = 'SPN'
  AND F.ST_DT = ''
  AND F.ST_ID_NUM = ''
GROUP BY A.CRSPD_SETID,
         A.CRSPD_CUST_ID,
         F.ST_ID_NUM,
         F.ST_DT,
         A.BUSINESS_UNIT ,
         H.ASOF_DT,
         H.DUE_DT,
         A.ITEM,
         H.CONTRACT_NUM,
         D.DESCR,
         G.DESCR,
         C.NAME1 ,
         B.ADDRESS1,
         B.ADDRESS2,
         B.ADDRESS3,
         B.ADDRESS4,
         B.CITY,
         B.STATE ,
         B.POSTAL,
         A.BAL_CURRENCY,
         A.CUST_ID,
         A.ENTRY_TYPE ,
         25,
         A.ENTRY_REASON,
         C.CUSTOMER_TYPE,
         K.AR_LVL,
         H.ORDER_NO
ORDER BY 2,
         3,
         4,
         25,
         8,
         11,
         24
```

Comment: I was reluctant to put something so giant into the question, but I guess it's not so bad since SO puts it in a `div` with a scrollbar.

Comment: The tool probably complains because the OUTER shorthand is considered "Informix-Extension" (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_1035.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Informix-style OUTER join is not simply a short cut for LEFT OUTER JOIN, but it is a moderate approximation to consider it as such.  There are a number of details why it is not that simple.

There's an online explanation for [Informix OUTER Joins](https://web.archive.org/web/20161118035919/http://savage.net.au/SQL/outer-joins.html), some of which are considerably more complex than the query in your example.

Translating the first half of your UNION query into a more modern notation, you'd get:

```
SELECT A.CRSPD_SETID,
       A.CRSPD_CUST_ID,
       F.ST_ID_NUM AS STMT_NBR,
       F.ST_DT,
       A.BUSINESS_UNIT,
       H.ASOF_DT,
       H.DUE_DT,
       A.ITEM,
       H.CONTRACT_NUM,
       D.DESCR AS ENTRY_TYPE_DESCR,
       G.DESCR AS ENTRY_REASON_DESCR,
       SUM(A.BAL_AMT) AS ORIG_BAL_AMT,
       SUM(H.BAL_AMT),
       C.NAME1,
       B.ADDRESS1,
       B.ADDRESS2,
       B.ADDRESS3,
       B.ADDRESS4,
       B.CITY,
       B.STATE,
       B.POSTAL,
       A.BAL_CURRENCY,
       A.CUST_ID,
       A.ENTRY_TYPE AS ORIG_ENTRY_TYPE,
       CASE
           WHEN A.ENTRY_TYPE = 'PY'
                OR A.ENTRY_TYPE = 'BGB' THEN 'AA' || substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3)
           ELSE substr(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3)
       END,
       A.ENTRY_REASON AS ORIG_ENTRY_REASON,
       C.CUSTOMER_TYPE,
       K.AR_LVL,
       H.ORDER_NO
  FROM PS_STMT_CUST_DTL A
  JOIN PS_CUST_ADDRESS B
    ON A.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM AND
       A.CRSPD_SETID = B.SETID AND
       A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = B.CUST_ID
  JOIN PS_CUSTOMER C
    ON B.SETID = C.SETID AND
       B.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID AND
       B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = C.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
  JOIN PS_SET_CNTRL_REC E
    ON E.SETCNTRLVALUE = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND
       E.RECNAME = 'ENTRY_TYPE_TBL'
  JOIN PS_STMT_CUST F
    ON A.CRSPD_SETID = F.CRSPD_SETID AND
       A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = F.CRSPD_CUST_ID AND
       A.ST_ID_NUM = F.ST_ID_NUM
  JOIN PS_ENTRY_REASN_TBL G
    ON G.ENTRY_TYPE = A.ENTRY_TYPE AND
       G.ENTRY_REASON = A.ENTRY_REASON AND
       G.SETID = E.SETID AND
  JOIN PS_ENTRY_TYPE_TBL D
    ON G.SETID = D.SETID AND
       G.ENTRY_TYPE = D.ENTRY_TYPE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_ITEM H
    ON A.BUSINESS_UNIT = H.BUSINESS_UNIT AND
       A.CUST_ID = H.CUST_ID AND
       A.ITEM = H.ITEM AND
       A.ITEM_LINE = H.ITEM_LINE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_BI_TYPE K
    ON SUBSTR(A.ENTRY_TYPE,1,3) = K.BILL_TYPE_ID
 WHERE B.EFFDT =
       (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT)
          FROM PS_CUST_ADDRESS B_ED
         WHERE B.SETID = B_ED.SETID
           AND B.CUST_ID = B_ED.CUST_ID
           AND B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = B_ED.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
           AND B_ED.EFFDT <= '06/19/2013')
   AND K.SETID = 'SPN'
   AND K.EFFDT =
       (SELECT MAX(C_ED.EFFDT)
          FROM PS_BI_TYPE C_ED
         WHERE K.SETID = C_ED.SETID
           AND K.BILL_TYPE_ID = C_ED.BILL_TYPE_ID
           AND C_ED.EFFDT <= '06/19/2013')
   AND K.EFF_STATUS = 'A'
   AND A.CRSPD_CUST_ID = '000331'
   AND A.CRSPD_SETID = 'SPN'
   AND F.ST_DT = ''
   AND F.ST_ID_NUM = ''
 GROUP BY A.CRSPD_SETID,
          A.CRSPD_CUST_ID,
          F.ST_ID_NUM,
          F.ST_DT,
          A.BUSINESS_UNIT ,
          H.ASOF_DT,
          H.DUE_DT,
          A.ITEM,
          H.CONTRACT_NUM,
          D.DESCR,
          G.DESCR,
          C.NAME1 ,
          B.ADDRESS1,
          B.ADDRESS2,
          B.ADDRESS3,
          B.ADDRESS4,
          B.CITY,
          B.STATE,
          B.POSTAL,
          A.BAL_CURRENCY,
          A.CUST_ID,
          A.ENTRY_TYPE,
          25,
          A.ENTRY_REASON,
          C.CUSTOMER_TYPE,
          K.AR_LVL,
          H.ORDER_NO
```

That's fairly complex because of the sheer number of tables and multi-column join conditions.  However, the outer join structure is straight-forward — both outer joins are related directly to the primary table, PS_STMT_CUST_DTL, which is given the alias A.

I'm fairly sure that the SQL could be simplified.  For example, when it was written, Informix probably didn't support 'sub-queries in the FROM clause'.  But the two SUM values could probably be put into a sub-query, and that would simplify the GROUP BY clause (eliminate it from the main query).

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct that OUTER is just shorthand (maybe Informix-flavored
>   shorthand) for LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Yes you are completely correct.

Quoting from a **[Informix-4GL Reference Manual](http://savage.net.au/SQL/outer-joins.html)**

> **Query 1 - Using a Simple Join**
>
> ```
> SELECT customer.customer_num, lname, order_num
>     FROM customer, orders
>     WHERE customer.customer_num = orders.order_num
> ```
>
> **Query 2 - Using an Outer Join**
>
> ```
> SELECT customer.customer_num, lname, order_num
>     FROM customer, OUTER orders
>     WHERE customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num
> ```

In Informix a join is specified as outer when OUTER is placed in front of the table that can contain null values.

Answer (score 1):

For information on Informix outer syntax:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fsqls.htm

IBM's funky documentation does not allow direct links, so search for OUTER in there.

This is for Informix 11.7, not sure what version you are using.

Essentially the outer tables will be subservient tables in ANY join condition in the where clause, and are effectively left outer joins. Also note the order the tables are specified in the from clause is significant with the Informix syntax.