# Bad results in SQL query

Tags: sql

I need to write a SQL query which Displays the Name of the Courses which the students have an average greater than 55 in it

TABLES : STUDENTS,GRADES,COURSES,DEPARTMENTS

WHAT I DID :

```
SQL> SELECT COURSE_NAME
  2  FROM COURSES
  3  where
  4  (select avg(grade) 
  5  from grades,courses
  6  where   
  7  grades.course_id=courses.course_id)>55;
```

and the result is bad ! (It displays all the courses)

TABLES :

```
 create table DEPARTMENTS
(
DEPARTMENT_ID char(2),
NAME varchar2(20),
HEAD varchar2(20));

 create table COURSES
 (
COURSE_ID char(10), 
COURSE_NAME varchar2(20),
TYPE char(6),
POINTS number(2),
DEPARTMENT_ID char(2));

create table GRADES
(
STUDENT_ID number(3),
COURSE_ID char(10), 
SEMESTER varchar2(10),
TERM char(1), 
GRADE number(3),
GRADE_SEM number(3));

create table STUDENTS   
(
STUDENT_ID number(3),
NAME char(15),
CITY char(15));
```

Comment: Should i add the tables ? because i dont think it may help

Comment: More information the better, but what are the numbers on the left? Perhaps accidentally copied over from your environment?

Comment: No .. the numbers is the commands counter .. it in SQLPLUS

Comment: We only need the tables that are relevant and also the columns would help as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query returns every record or no records from `COURSES` based on whether the subquery returns more than 55 or less than 55, because the outer query is not related to the subquery in any way.  You want to `JOIN` the tables, `GROUP BY` the course name, and use a `HAVING` clause to filter:

```
SELECT c.course_name 
FROM grades g
JOIN courses c
  ON   g.course_id = c.course_id
GROUP BY c.course_name
HAVING AVG(grade) > 55
```

Comment: Ah ! it works , but what if i wanted to find the maximum of all averages of courses grades ?

I do ( **HAVING MAX(AVG(GRADE))** ) ?

Comment: If you wanted to find all that had the max average grade, you could use a subquery in the having clause:  `HAVING AVG(grade) = (SELECT MAX(AVG(grade) OVER(PARTITION BY course_id)) max_avg_gd FROM grades)`

Comment: No . its not "ALL" .. i am talking about a course for every course there are average of grades now from all the averages of courses .. i need to find the maximum average of a single course , 
And ah ! am sorry .. i need to find the COURSE_ID of the maximum of all averages .. not the maximum value

Answer (score -1):

Try this query :

```
select COURSE_NAME,  avg(grade) from grades,courses where grades.course_id=courses.course_id
group by COURSE_NAME
having avg(grade) > 55
```

Comment: why are you using old style joins??

Comment: Because it's simple query :)

Comment: that makes it worse... a simple query should look simple!

Comment: @Hogan, why not use this Joins, can you explain me ? or because it's old ?

Comment: Because old style joins are harder to understand and not as clear.

Comment: Here is a good answer that explains better than I ever could >> http://stackoverflow.com/a/11251836/215752

Answer (score -1):

This is your subquery:

select avg(grade) 
from grades,courses
where
grades.course_id=courses.course_id

Try running that query first. You should see it return a single number. But there is nothing else attached to that number. So the outer query can't do anything with it except return all courses.

Comment: why are you using old style joins??

Comment: @Hogan They are quoting OP and telling them what they ARE doing wrong.