# Efficiency in SQL

Tags: sql

What is more efficiency: to do update with `join` or to do update with `where`.

Here is my code:

**Join**:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[MyProc]
@tvp myType readonly
as
 update tb
 set pp_update=CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),101)
 from myTable tb
 join @tvp t on t.crc32 = tb.pp_crc32
```

**Where**:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[MyProc]
@tvp myType readonly
as
 update tb
 set pp_update=CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),101)
 from myTable tb
 where t.crc32 = tb.pp_crc32
```

What is prefer? and if I have 2 terms can I use `join`??

Comment: The second query wont work as you haven't established what `t` is. The only way you'll ever really know is to profile it, but I would expect the performance of both to be comparable - it's a perennial question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo error at the second query. Maybe you mean

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[MyProc]
@tvp myType readonly
as
 update tb
 set pp_update=CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),101)
 from myTable tb, @tvp t
 where t.crc32 = tb.pp_crc32
```

The two queries are the same. The only thing is that the first query is in `ANSI SQL-92` syntax while the other one is the `SQL-89` (old one) syntax.

Comment: thanks, and if I have 2 terms, can I use with the first syntax?

Comment: the first syntax is much better since it is more clear than the second one.