# Optimize SQL select query with join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
 Shop_Products
 Shop_Products_Egenskaber_Overruling
```

I want to select all records in Shop_Products_Egenskaber_Overruling which has a related record in 
Shop_Products. This Means a record with an equal ProductNum.

This Works for me with the statement below, but I don't think a CROSS JOIN is the best approach for large record sets. When using the statement in web controls, it becomes pretty slow, even with only 1000 records. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
 SELECT     Shop_Products.*, Shop_Products_Egenskaber_Overruling.*
 FROM       Shop_Products CROSS JOIN
            Shop_Products_Egenskaber_Overruling
 WHERE      Shop_Products.ProductNum = Shop_Products_Egenskaber_Overruling.ProductNum
```

Any optimizing suggestions?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually looking for an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT 
    SO.*,
    SPEO.*
FROM SHOP_PRODUCTS SP 
    INNER JOIN Shop_Products_Egenskaber_Overruling SPEO 
        ON SP.ProductNum = SPEO.ProductNum
```

This will have improved performance over your CROSS-JOIN, because the condition to look for records with equal ProductNum is implicit in the `JOIN` condition and the `WHERE` clause is eliminated.

`WHERE` clauses always execute AFTER a JOIN. In your case, all possible combinations are created by the CROSS JOIN and then filtered by the conditions in the WHERE clause.

By using an `INNER JOIN` you are doing the filtering in the first step.

Comment: Thanks for the working solution and the explanation! It really boosted the load time...

Comment: @micknt You're welcome. Just as a side note, CROSS JOIN should always be your last option in term of JOINS.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it that way but not sure it will ensure an optimization

```
SELECT     Shop_Products.*, Shop_Products_Egenskaber_Overruling.*
FROM       Shop_Products 
INNER JOIN Shop_Products_Egenskaber_Overruling on Shop_Products.ProductNum = Shop_Products_Egenskaber_Overruling.ProductNum
```

Comment: Thank you, inner join was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Cross join is slower, because it produce all combinations, which filtred after by where predicate. So you can use INNER JOIN for better performance. But I think It would be useful if you check execution plan of this query anyway, because in Oracle there is no difference between where and inner join solutions [Inner join vs Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where)

Comment: Thank you, inner join was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try using INNER JOIN

```
SELECT     Produkter.*, Egenskaber.*
FROM       Shop_Products Produkter
INNER JOIN Shop_Products_Egenskaber_Overruling Egenskaber ON Produkter.ProductNum=Egenskaber.ProductNum
```

Jag namngav aven dem pa Norska..

Comment: Thank you, inner join was the solution!