# Linq to Entities From vs Join

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

Is there a difference when joining many to many tables when using the 'from' clauses, or the 'join' clauses? Resultsets that come back are the same.

Take for example three tables in a many to many relationship (including a junction table): Students, StudentCourses, Courses:

```
var query = from student in context.Students
            from studentcourse in student.StudentCourses
            where studentcourse.CourseID == 4
            select student;


var query = from student in context.Students
            join studentcourse in context.StudentCourses
            on student.StudentID equals studentcourse.StudentID
            where studentcourse.CourseID == 4
            select student;
```

1. Would either of them be best practice?
2. Performance? Is one better than the other? I haven't had a chance to SQL Profiler either of them.

I'm avoiding using Include for two reasons:

1. I require conditional includes more often than not, hence the two techniques above.
2. From what I've read, Include returns the entire related table, could be taxing for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, LINQ to Entities will create two different queries, where your first example will use a WHERE and the second one will JOIN the tables. However this will have no effect on performance, as the SQL optimizer will create the same execution plans for both these queries. See [Inner join vs Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where)

best practices wise, the first option is almost always preferable. Using navigation properties makes your code easier to read and understand and removes the hassle of having to join the tables yourself.