# Is there any way to optimize this select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, query-optimization

So i'm having this big select witch used with union. I'm thinking, is there any way to optimize it, because it's now quite heavy.

As you can see the main difference is between joined tables (`srv_obj_intermediate` and `srv_obj_attributes`) and they have 2 different `oet.code`

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT soi.value, srv.osp_id, soi.stya_id, eax.estpt_id, eax.discount, seo.id AS sero_id FROM estimate_attr_xref eax
                    JOIN attribute_types attl ON attl.id = eax.attr_id
                    JOIN object_attr_type_links oatl ON oatl.attr_id = attl.id
                    JOIN service_type_attributes sta ON sta.objt_attr_id = oatl.id
                    JOIN srv_obj_intermediate soi ON soi.stya_id = sta.id
                        AND ((soi.value = 0) OR (soi.value = 1 AND festpae_id IS NOT NULL))
                    JOIN service_objects seo ON seo.id = soi.sero_id
                    JOIN services srv ON srv.id = seo.srv_id
                    JOIN order_event oet ON oet.code = 'INTERMEDIATE'
                    WHERE eax.rate = 1 AND eax.ordet_id = oet.id
                    AND eax.objt_attr_id = sta.objt_attr_id) WHERE value = 1

                    UNION

                    SELECT soa.value, srv.osp_id, soa.stya_id, eax.estpt_id, eax.discount, seo.id AS sero_id FROM estimate_attr_xref eax
                    JOIN attribute_types attl ON attl.id = eax.attr_id
                    JOIN object_attr_type_links oatl ON oatl.attr_id = attl.id
                    JOIN service_type_attributes sta ON sta.objt_attr_id = oatl.id
                    JOIN srv_obj_attributes soa ON soa.stya_id = sta.id
                        AND soa.value = 1
                    LEFT JOIN srv_obj_intermediate soi ON soi.stya_id = sta.id
                        AND soi.value = 1
                    JOIN service_objects seo ON seo.id = soa.sero_id
                    JOIN services srv ON srv.id = seo.srv_id
                    JOIN order_event oet ON oet.code = 'INITIAL'
                    WHERE eax.rate = 1 AND eax.ordet_id = oet.id
                    AND eax.objt_attr_id = sta.objt_attr_id AND soi.value IS NULL
```

Comment: Have you done an explain plan to look for full table scans? What indexes & indexing options do you have? Which are your largest tables? How about partitioning? Do you have existing partitions, or places where it would make sense? There are many factors that could be contributing to your query's poor performance.

Comment: One thing that stands out, that can sometimes cause slowness, and that is easy to fix, is `UNION` instead of the much more common (and much faster) `UNION ALL`. Do you know how many rows each of the members of the `UNION` produce? If even one of the two is "many rows", this will be an issue. Or do you actually did mean `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: @mathguy Yea, i mean `UNION`, it should be used.
There is no problems in this select in total(he executes fast enough), the questions is only from the optimization side, because lines get duplicated and thought maybe there is a way to make it more compact?

Comment: Agree with @Acroyear that there could be many factors and it's hard to tell without knowing the underlying structure and volume of your data

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance and without having any insight into your data, relationships, volumes, indexes, partitioning, cpu etc.

(1) In the first outer select (i.e. before UNION), you seem to have a filter `WHERE VALUE = 1` where value is actually `soe.value`. In the inner select you have a condition `((soi.value = 0) OR (soi.value = 1 AND festpae_id IS NOT NULL))`. Wouldn't it suffice to just use `soi.value = 1 AND festpae_id IS NOT NULL` in the inner select and avoid an outer select? What soi.value are you looking for?

(2) Similarly, in the second select you have `LEFT JOIN srv_obj_intermediate soi ON soi.stya_id = sta.id` and further down you have a filter `AND soi.value IS NULL`. Again, what `soi.value` are you looking for?

(3) Consider moving the oet.code filter predicate under the where clause and use `JOIN order_event oet ON eax.ordet_id = oet.id` for reasons mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330234/oracle-sql-query-filter-in-join-on-vs-where), although this doesn't guarantee peformance improvement. You'll need to review if and how the execution plan changes in each case.

(4) Are stats up-to-date on all these tables?

(5) Have you reviewed the [plan](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i17492)? Are you missing any joins and/or having cartesian joins in the plan? Are you seeing full table scans when you expect usage of an index or expect partition pruning? [This](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-explain-the-explain-plan-052011-393674.pdf) white paper is a good starting point if you're unfamiliar with explain plans.