# SQL Join with Table Alias in PLSQL Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am playing around and am trying to make something like this work and can't find a way around. I do a join in a sql statement with table alias'.

How do I then access these items in a PLSQL for loop?

```
SELECT    
    it.item_title title,
    r.item_id id
FROM 
    item it, rental_item r
WHERE 
    it.item_id = r.item_id;
```

I would like to know if there is a way to access them in a loop like this given that the query above is a `cursor or for i in (query)`...

```
FOR i IN c LOOP
  dbms_output.print_line(i.title||' '||i.id);
END LOOP;
```

Right now I am using a static cursor and filling a table of records with the data and then manipulating it. However, if this problem can be solved in this fashion it would be much more elegant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1
IS
SELECT    
    it.item_title title, r.item_id id
FROM 
    item it inner join, rental_item r
    on it.item_id = r.item_id;
BEGIN
FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
   dbms_output.print_line(rec.title||' '||rec.id);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Funny, I tried this exact thing earlier using `FOR i IN..` and it didn't work. However, this code works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Also for future reference, you cannot use `AS "title"` as you would in SQL. You can only use `it.item_title title`.

Comment: always give the best answer with appropriate best knowledge, you can suggest as I edited your answer of join cluase. Joining with comma and where cluase is very old as well as performance impact query.

Comment: I won't argue about it, but it will run the same either way in Oracle. There's no performance difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where