# MySQL: How to show rows Not Having certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a bit of an issue with the following query.

```
SELECT su.display_name, su.user_email, sm.meta_value FROM system_users AS su
JOIN system_usermeta AS sm ON su.ID = sm.user_id
WHERE sm.meta_key = 'market';
```

The above query works fine to show all users and their values who have 'market' set in the meta_key column.

But how can I turn this around?
How could I show all the users which don't have the meta_key 'market' associated with their user_ID.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT su.display_name, su.user_email, sm.meta_value FROM system_users AS su
JOIN system_usermeta AS sm ON su.ID = sm.user_id
WHERE sm.meta_key <> 'market';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a more complex query for this . . . because you are checking multiple rows.  Aggregation is one approach:

```
SELECT su.display_name, su.user_email
FROM system_users su JOIN
     system_usermeta sm
     ON su.ID = sm.user_id
GROUP BY su.display_name, su.user_email
HAVING SUM( sm.meta_key = 'market' ) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `LEFT JOIN` because you want to add a filter in the left table and show data from right table, so try this:

```
SELECT su.display_name, su.user_email, sm.meta_value 
FROM system_users AS su
LEFT JOIN system_usermeta AS sm ON su.ID = sm.user_id
      AND sm.meta_key <> 'market';
```

---

If you want to filter users that haven't any `meta_key` with `'market'` try this:

```
SELECT su.display_name, su.user_email, sm.meta_value 
FROM system_users AS su
LEFT JOIN system_usermeta AS sm ON su.ID = sm.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM system_usermeta smi
    WHERE su.ID = smi.user_id AND smi.meta_key = 'market')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether `sm.meta_key` is not `'market'`, then you can use Thanos Markou's solution

```
SELECT su.display_name, su.user_email, sm.meta_value FROM system_users AS su
JOIN system_usermeta AS sm ON su.ID = sm.user_id
WHERE sm.meta_key <> 'market';
```

or, if you want to check that `sm.meta_key` does not contain `'market'`, then this is how you can do it:

```
SELECT su.display_name, su.user_email, sm.meta_value FROM system_users AS su
JOIN system_usermeta AS sm ON su.ID = sm.user_id
WHERE sm.meta_key not like '%market%';
```

If it might be `'Market'`, then you can make the text lower case to have a case-insensitive check.

Answer (score 0):

Is a join clause necessary?

```
SELECT su.display_name, su.user_email, sm.meta_value FROM system_users AS su,system_usermeta AS sm where su.ID = sm.user_id
AND sm.meta_key <> 'market';
```

Comment: Apparently, eliminating join doesn't add to any advantage.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where

Answer (score -1):

Use This

```
SELECT su.display_name, su.user_email, sm.meta_value FROM system_users AS su
JOIN system_usermeta AS sm ON su.ID = sm.user_id
WHERE sm.meta_key != 'market';
```

Comment: hey down-voter , what is reason of down voting ? Don't just down-vote specify the reason for down-voting