# SELECT ... WHERE IN vs JOIN

Tags: sql, database, performance, processing-efficiency

Assume we have 4 tables A, B, C, D in **some unspecified relational SQL database**. A references B, also C and D as well. References means that A has column A.refX_id = X.id, X is A, B and C (common foreign key 1:N).

What I want, is to query table A with condition based on columns from all child tables B, C and D. My question is: **What of the following variants is generally better?** (In terms of usability, efficiency, speed.)

*Variant 1:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* FROM A
   JOIN B ON A.refB_id = B.id
   JOIN C ON A.refC_id = C.id
   JOIN D ON A.refD_id = D.id
   WHERE <condition on B> AND <condition on C> AND <condition on D>;
```

Which I like more from perspective of a database, but looks a little bit harder to program.

*Variant 2:*

```
SELECT id FROM B WHERE <condition on B>; # result store to array "BIds" on program side
SELECT id FROM C WHERE <condition on C>; # result store to array "CIds" on program side
SELECT id FROM D WHERE <condition on D>; # result store to array "DIds" on program side

SELECT A.* FROM A
   WHERE refB_id IN (<B_ids>) AND refC_id IN (<C_ids>) AND refD_id IN (<D_ids>);

# <B_ids> menas expand whole array of ids, which can result in a very long query string
```

I thought that *Variant 2* is completelly smut and unusable with potentially large data. But I've heard, that a lot of frameworks normally use it, because it is relativelly straightforward. Is it sort of legal way to query data like this in general case, if I know that the content of the "IN" clause is taken from a result of another query(ies)?

Comment: Was just looking up this very question and found this response:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would encourage you to use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE A.refB_id = B.id AND <condition on B>) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM C WHERE A.refC_id = C.id AND <condition on C>) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM D WHERE A.refD_id = D.id AND <condition on D>);
```

Advantages of this approach:

- No danger of getting large intermediate Cartesian products.
- No expense of eliminating duplicates for `SELECT DISTINCT`.
- Most databases handle `EXISTS` pretty well.
- You can optimize each subquery using indexes.

EDIT:

You can write this with `IN` and subqueries:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
WHERE A.refB_id IN (SELECT B.id FROM B WHERE <condition on B>) AND
      A.refC_id IN (SELECT C.id FROM C WHERE <condition on C>) AND
      A.refD_id IN (SELECT D.id FROM D WHERE <condition on D>);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have never seen SELECT 1... How would it looks like with IN? Did you mean that Variant1??

Comment: Yes, this is more readable. Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @David I disagree about readability but it depends on what you are used to seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which framework uses the 2nd approach but first approach is what I will go for and moreover everyone else will. If you have proper index created on the join column for all tables then 1st approach will produce a much better plan than the 2nd one cause you have multiple `IN` clause and what if every `IN` has to work on millions of elements???.

Also, I would  change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` assuming that not all ID's may match and move the `WHERE` conditions to `JOIN ON` conditions like

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* FROM A
   LEFT JOIN B ON A.refB_id = B.id AND <condition on B>
   LEFT JOIN C ON A.refC_id = C.id AND <condition on C>
   LEFT JOIN D ON A.refD_id = D.id AND <condition on D>;
```