# Count of Items Based on Todays Date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables one has the `user_info` and another has `user_activies`.

I have a query that fetches several rows from `user_info` table. What I want to add to this query is;

I want to fetch **todays** user activities and **count** them from `user_activities` table.

```
user_info
| id | name | views | lastlogin | regdate | group_id |

user_activities
| id | userid | activity | date |
```

Current query

```
select id, name, views, lastlogin 
from user_info 
where group_id = 2 
ORDER BY user_info.id ASC
```

How could I concatenate count of the total number of activities has been done **today**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide minimal sample data and then expected output from this data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm assuming that date is of type date:

```sql
select 
   u.id,
   u.name,
   u.views,
   u.lastlogin,
    sum(
  -- if datetime IF (date(date) = curdate() , 1, 0)
  IF (date = curdate() , 1, 0)
     ) as 'today_activities'

from user_info u 
      -- using left join you will get the list of all user even if they
      -- don't have any activities today with sum activities= 0
      LEFT JOIN user_activities a on u.id = a.userid
where 
   group_id = 2
group by u.id
ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

Comment: i edit my answer to handle datetime if the type is datetime

Comment: Is there a performance difference between using a `JOIN` instead of using 2 tables in the `FROM` clause?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where take a look at this answer

Comment: @CherifOdoo Hi Cherif, my date type is text but stored as date format such as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. How could I count the date when my date stored in text type?

Comment: ok you need to convert it there is a function for that i think wait a minute

Comment: Thanks to @MartinB. I have managed to make this work. I used your code and changed `date = curdate()` to `date(date) = curdate()` and also updated `u.id = a.user_activities` to `u.id = a.userid`

Comment: `IF (date(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d')) = curdate() , 1, 0)`

Comment: @CherifOdoo This has also worked, thank you both I really apprecaite! :-)

Comment: sorry for my mistake on joining

Answer (score 2):

<del>You want this:</del>

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.views, i.lastlogin, Count(a.id)
  FROM user_info i, user_activities a
  WHERE i.group_id = 2 AND i.id = a.userid
    AND a.date = CURDATE()
  ORDER BY user_info.id ASC;
```

<del>This gives you a record of every user with a count of todays activities. (You may need to change the `a.date = CURDATE()` to fit your timestamp needs)</del>

This will not give you a list of ervery user. Instead you will have to select a single user. If you select multiple users you will get a random name with the sum of all activities from all selected users.
Or short: **This does not solve your problem.** Take the `JOIN`-solution.

Comment: Hi! This returns null for some reason, by the way my date type is `date text utf8_general_ci` but stored as this format: `2017-04-28 11:33:05`

Comment: I just found out that this solution is flawed. It does not work for multiple users.

Comment: Also you will have to strip the time from this timestamp using `DATE(date)` to get the yyy-mm-dd part of the date and compare it with the current day.

Comment: @MartinB. goo job too ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.views, i.lastlogin, Count(a.activities)
  FROM user_info i inner join user_activities a
  WHERE i.group_id = 2 AND i.id = a.userid
    AND a.date = now()
  ORDER BY user_info.id
```