# Can I use where clause instead of AND in given SQL query? If yes, whats the difference in both?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Came across this query online some where, explaining inner join with a condition (incentive>3k).Was just wondering if I can use where clause instead of 'AND' in below SQL, if yes, whats will be the output difference in both?

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,
       INCENTIVE_AMOUNT
FROM employee a
     INNER JOIN incentives B ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_REF_ID
                                AND INCENTIVE_AMOUNT > 3000;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner join vs Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121631/inner-join-vs-where)

Comment: Do you ask about MySql or Oracle because you've tagged both

Comment: On a sidenote: `a` and `b` are bad alias names. Use mnemonic names instead to get the query more readable, e.g. `FROM employee e JOIN incentives i ON ...`. Then, when using multiple tables, use qualifiers for *all* columns, i.e. also on `FIRST_NAME` and `INCENTIVE_AMOUNT` in your query, to increase readability and maintainability. At last you should stick to a pattern for lower / upper case, e.g. keywords in upper case, names in lower case, as in  `FROM employee e INNER JOIN incentives i ON i.employee_ref_id = e.employee_id`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I asked it from Oracle point of view. Thank you for suggesting Best code practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They come to the same thing.

However, it is generally considered good practice to use `join` clauses only for specifying joins, and keep filter predicates in the `where` clause, hence:

```
select first_name, incentive_amount
from   employee e
       join incentives i
            on  i.employee_ref_id = e.employee_id
where  i.incentive_amount > 3000
```

(Note that the `inner` and `outer` keywords are optional and in my view redundant clutter, so I never use them.)

In the case of outer joins (`left join`, or if you absolutely must, `left outer join`), the whole idea of separating the filter predicates and placing them in the `where` clause goes out of the window, because (for example) if there is no `incentive` row then `i.incentive_amount` will be null and so any predicate whatsoever will exclude the row. Some say this is why ANSI join syntax is rubbish and the distinction between join and filter predicates is artificial and pointless, while others see it as a quirk of an otherwise helpful syntax.

```
select first_name, incentive_amount
from   employee e
       left join incentives i
            on  i.employee_ref_id = e.employee_id
            and i.incentive_amount > 3000
```

You could still follow the convention for inner joins in the same query, e.g:

```
select first_name, incentive_amount
from   employee e
       join departments d
            on d.department_id = e.department_id
       left join incentives i
            on  i.employee_ref_id = e.employee_id
            and i.incentive_amount > 3000
where  d.name = 'Philology'
```

Just to add, I agree with [Jonathan Lewis](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2006/11/02/clarity-clarity-clarity/) that `a` and `b` are terrible aliases for `employee` and `incentives`. (By the way, why not `employees` or `incentive`?) In my version I have used the surely more readable `e` and `i`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can try this

```
Select FIRST_NAME,INCENTIVE_AMOUNT from employee
     inner join incentives B on A.EMPLOYEE_ID=B.EMPLOYEE_REF_ID 
where INCENTIVE_AMOUNT >3000
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use it

```
Select FIRST_NAME,INCENTIVE_AMOUNT from 
employee inner join incentives B on 
A.EMPLOYEE_ID=B.EMPLOYEE_REF_ID 
where INCENTIVE_AMOUNT >3000
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Oracle but, at least for `INNER JOIN`, MySQL treats the `WHERE` conditions the same as the join conditions. It checks all of them that can be checked as soon as possible while it computes each row to put in the result set.

These two queries produce the same resultset (and afaik MySQL processes them about the same way):

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, INCENTIVE_AMOUNT
FROM employee a
  INNER JOIN incentives B 
     ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_REF_ID AND INCENTIVE_AMOUNT > 3000
```

and

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, INCENTIVE_AMOUNT
FROM employee a
  INNER JOIN incentives B 
WHERE A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_REF_ID AND INCENTIVE_AMOUNT > 3000
```

There is no difference in the output of `INNER JOIN` but if you move the join conditions in the `WHERE` clause of a `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` you get a different result set.

The query:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, INCENTIVE_AMOUNT
FROM employee a
  LEFT JOIN incentives B 
     ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_REF_ID AND INCENTIVE_AMOUNT > 3000
```

includes in the result set all the rows from table `employee`, matching with a row full of `NULL`s the rows that do not have a match (on the join condition) in table `b`.

But this query:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, INCENTIVE_AMOUNT
FROM employee a
  LEFT JOIN incentives B 
WHERE A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_REF_ID AND INCENTIVE_AMOUNT > 3000
```

combines all the rows of table `a` with all rows of table `b` and then the `WHERE` clause keeps only the matching rows from the two tables. Its output is identical with the above two `INNER JOIN` queries.